# Recipients.Add generates Runtime error '287': Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I am testing how to send an e-mail. I have copied the code below from the help files:

```
Sub CreateHTMLMail()
'Creates a new e-mail item and modifies its properties'

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    'Create e-mail item'
    Set objMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With objMail
        .Subject = "Test Message"
        .Body = "Body Text"
        .Recipients.Add "xyz@abc.com"
        .Recipients.ResolveAll
        .Display
    End With
End Sub
```

I receive a Runtime error '287' message with the .Recipients.Add line highlighted. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a quick comment... if you want the message to send automatically without having to open outlook, just use the `.Send` property at the end of your `With`

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
As the OP states in his comment to my original answer, changing his code to

```
.Recipients.To = "abc@xyz.com"
```

solved his problem. I leave my original answer below, because someone may learn from the mistake I made, pointed out by [divo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40347/divo) ;-)

---

**Original answer (careful, this is wrong!):**

> Try  enclosing the parameters passed to the *Add* method with parentheses:
>       .Recipients.Add ("xyz@abc.com")

Comment: Tried that with the same result

Comment: changed .Recipients.Add line to .To = ("abc@xyz.com) and that worked

Comment: @Treb: Since this is VBA there is no need for brackets on a method call. This is one of the biggest misunderstandings in VBA (which actually can introduce bugs).

Comment: ...(continued) See here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070863/hidden-features-of-vba/1070942#1070942

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   toString = "me@email.com;you@email.com;them@email.com"

    With OutMail
        .To = toString
        .Subject = "Hello Friends"
        .Body = "Here is the email body"
        .Send
    End With
```

This of course works with multiple recipients. For a single recipient, just do this:

```
toString = "oneguy@gmail.com"
```

And don't forget the `.Send` to actually make your email send.