# Open Default E-mail Client using .Vbs file

Tags: vba, vbscript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send e-mail through VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265270/send-e-mail-through-vba)
>   [Send email from Excel in Exchange environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122747/send-email-from-excel-in-exchange-environment)

I have this so far

```
Dim objOutl
Set objOutl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMailItem = objOutl.CreateItem(olMailItem)
objMailItem.Display
strEmailAddr  = "me.me@you.com"
objMailItem.Recipients.Add strEmailAddr
objMailItem.Body = "Hi"
objMailItem.Attachments.Add "access.xml"
Set objMailItem = nothing
Set objOutl = nothing
```

It works! But only on computers that have Outlook. How can I get this to work with computers that have Windows Live?

Comment: What application will run this script? e.g Access do have options to send an mail via `DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, , acFormatHTML, empfängerMail, , , betreff, mailText`

Comment: I just run the .vbs File, I am not familiar with them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recipients.Add generates Runtime error '287': Application-defined or object-defined error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265270/recipients-add-generates-runtime-error-287-application-defined-or-object-defi)

Answer (score 1):

Windows Live Mail (WLM) doesn't support automation via VBA, so it isn't as straightforward as with Outlook.

For other options, try typing `[vba] e-mail` in the search field. You'll get quite a few hits; here is a relevant sample: [Hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330897/how-to-send-a-mail-automatically/933217), [hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265270/send-e-mail-through-vba), [hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122747/send-email-from-excel-in-exchange-environment). Some of these give you working code for sending mail using CDO. This is what I would do if I were you.

If you *must* use WLM, then have a look at [this mail add-ins for Excel](http://www.rondebruin.nl/mail/add-in.htm) which does support WLM.

Otherwise you're stuck using VBA's `SendMail` method, which is very limited:

- Can only send an Excel object such as a sheet, workbook, chart, range, etc.
- Can't write text in the body of the e-mail
- Can't use the CC or BCC fields
- Can't attach files (other than the Excel object calling the method)

Example code:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
wb.SendMail "me.me@you.com", _
            "Insert subject here"
```

For more examples look here: http://www.rondebruin.nl/sendmail.htm

Answer (score 0):

the following suppose to work on access (vba) (code is not mine):

```
Public Function send_email()

Set cdomsg = CreateObject("CDO.message")
With cdomsg.Configuration.Fields
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 'NTLM method
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smptserverport") = 587
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") =   "mygmail@gmail.com"
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "mypassword"
.Update
End With
' build email parts With cdomsg
.To = "somebody@somedomain.com"
.From = "mygmail@gmail.com"
.Subject = "the email subject"
.TextBody = "the full message body goes here. you may want to create a variable to hold  the text"
.Send
End With
Set cdomsg = Nothing
End Function
```

note if you want to use other email service you should alter the code a bit.

some other options here - [msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms872547%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx)

Hope it helps.