# Open default email client (outlook, thunderbird, gmail, etc.) with attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, mailto

I looked at a bunch of tutorials using `ActionMailer`, but they all seem to just automatically send emails without opening up a default email app. I want the user to be able to click a button that opens up their default email client with the `to` and `subject` fields filled in, and be able to have a file attached. Ideally, I want it to work just like:

```
<a href='mailto:someperson@example.com'>
```

but have it able to attach a file. I would post code, but I have no idea what to post. I guess the main question is if there's a way to get `ActionMailer` to open up outlook instead of just sending emails?

There is very similar question, [Rails actionmailer open host email app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104313/rails-actionmailer-open-host-email-app) but the solutions didn't work.

**update**

My app is for a small workplace where every computer has access to whatever files are needed which would be located on the server. I am trying to make it so that the user of the app can click an email button which grabs a pdf file from a folder on the server and opens up outlook on their machine with the file automatically attached.

Comment: Rails ActionMailer runs on a server, where the Mail program is on a users computer.

Comment: @dre-hh so what does that mean for my question? please see my edit for more information about what i'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Checked the edit. Still different machines, right? So - Impossibru!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it seems you can't use the mailto shell to add attachments from what google has told me BUT:

The way I'd approach it is through a client side script or executable and the serverside trigger (the button on a website).

I'd personally use a compiled autohotkey script but here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268942/open-default-e-mail-client-using-vbs-file) to a vbs/vba script (only works with outlook).

Hope this points you in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible. You'll have to write a native app or a browser extension for that.

See [Attaching a file in email in html5 web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228703/attaching-a-file-in-email-in-html5-web-page)

Comment: Hiya, looks like you've linked to another stack overflow question. Is this a duplicate of that question? If so - you can always flag a question as a duplicate - which tends to give a nicer linking between the two than just adding it as an "answer".