# Edit Send To Mail Recipient behavior

Tags: windows, sendmail, windows-live-mail

My default email client is Windows Live Mail. When I right click on a file and select **Send To->Mail Recipient** Windows Live Mail New Message Window pops up, file is attached but body and subject are filled and I want them to be empty. Also, I want to Recipient (**To:** field) be filled with predefined address. What I found out so far:

1. *Windows Live Mail (WLM) doesn't support automation via VBA* so can't use vb scripting. [Open Default E-mail Client using .Vbs file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268942/open-default-e-mail-client-using-vbs-file).
2. *Note that you cannot attach files from the command line* so can't create custom shortcut in Send To folder. [Create a Message in Windows Live Mail or Outlook Express from the Command Line](http://email.about.com/od/outlookexpresshacks/qt/Command_Line_Mail_in_Windows_Live_Mail_or_Outlook_Express.htm)

Comment: Use Simple MAPI to customize the composition window.

Comment: Looks ok, except that Windows Live Mail displays message that some program is attempting to send mail :(

Comment: So what I did is sent mail using mapi but i don't want to do this. I want to show **Windows Live Mail New Message Window** with empty subject and body, filled recipeint and file attached.