# Adding variable number of objects to collection

Tags: vba, oop

I understand adding objects to a collection can be done by

```
Dim ItemList As Collection
Set ItemList = New Collection

Dim Item As New CItem

Set Shoe = New CItem
      With Shoe
           .Quantity
           .IDNumber 
           .Description
      End With
ItemList.Add Shoe

Set Bag = New CItem
      With Bag
           .Quantity
           .IDNumber 
           .Description
      End With
ItemList.Add Bag
```

I would be able to call data i want to use like (Cost = Bag.Quantity * 2)

However my problem is that my list of items will be user defined. Is there any way to add a variable number of objects into a collection and still be able to retrieve individual data by the item name?

for example, i am given a list of items: Shoe, Bag, Sunglasses, Pants

I would like to write a for loop to read all these objects under the class "Item" but still be able to calculate (xyz = Sunglasses.Quantity + Pants.Quantity - Bag.Quantity). I have tried to use counters, but it seems to only accept constant expressions.

Is this possible? If so, i would appreciate help in finding out how to do it.

Comment: I'm not an expert on OOP in VBA, so I'm not sure for the name retreveing, but you could create an `Item` class and define a `Type` property to do this (except if your items are far too different from each other and then it can be messy in the properties)

Comment: [**1**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19908375/2140173) and [**2**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19379641/2140173) to get you started on interfaces and oop in VBA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an item to collection with key:

```
ItemList.Add Shoe, "Shoe"
```

and then retrieve it by specifying this key:

```
Dim Shoe As CItem
Set Shoe = ItemList.Item("Shoe")
```

Comment: Thank you that works just fine. Thank you stakx for the prompt reply as well

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Set Shoe = New CItem
>       With Shoe
>            .Quantity
>            .IDNumber 
>            .Description
>       End With
> ```

Note that the `CItem` object you are creating here does not have a property that describes the object's type. That is, if you look only at the object, there is no way to tell that it "is a shoe". All you know about such an object is a quantity, an ID number, and a description.

You named the variable `Shoe`; but that is just the variable's name, not the referred object's.

What you need to do is to add some kind of `.Type` or `.Category` property so that your objects become self-descriptive. Your above code would be amended with one more line like this:

```
Shoe.Category = "Shoe"
```

This makes it possible to take a collection of `CItem`s, iterate over them, and sum up the quantities per `.Category`.

But the objects in your list will no longer have a dedicated variable name each.

Comment: mm i do not really see how i can apply what you have answered in to a loop for iterative data mining