# Object Module needs to implement '~' for interface '~'

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I tried following these questions as guides:

- [How to use the Implements in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373081/how-to-use-the-implements-in-excel-vba)
- [How to use comparison methods between class object modules in VBA in a similar manner as VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19881863/how-to-use-comparison-methods-between-class-object-modules-in-vba-in-a-similar-m/19908375#19908375)

Here is the error I'm getting whenever I click a control on my form:

[image: error_msg]

Here is my interface:

**ITransactionRecord**

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Property Get TRANSACTION_DATE() As Date
End Property
```

Here are my classes:

**LedgerRecord**

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Implements ITransactionRecord

'from interface
Private tTRANSACTION_DATE As Date

Private Property Get ITransactionRecord_TRANSACTION_DATE() As Date
    ITransactionRecord_TRANSACTION_DATE = TRANSACTION_DATE
End Property

Public Property Get TRANSACTION_DATE() As Date
    TRANSACTION_DATE = tTRANSACTION_DATE
End Property

Public Property Let TRANSACTION_DATE(ByVal newTRANSACTION_DATE As Date)
    tTRANSACTION_DATE = CDate(Format((newTRANSACTION_DATE), "m / d / yyyy"))
End Property
```

**TransferRecord**

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Implements ITransactionRecord

'from interface
Private tTRANSACTION_DATE As Date

Private Property Get ITransactionRecord_TRANSACTION_DATE() As Date
    ITransactionRecord_TRANSACTION_DATE = TRANSACTION_DATE
End Property

Public Property Get TRANSACTION_DATE() As Date
    TRANSACTION_DATE = tTRANSACTION_DATE
End Property

Public Property Let TRANSACTION_DATE(ByVal newTRANSACTION_DATE As Date)
    tTRANSACTION_DATE = CDate(Format((newTRANSACTION_DATE), "m / d / yyyy"))
End Property
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> Public Property Get TRANSACTION_DATE() As Date
> End Property
> ```

You can't have an underscore in a public interface member name in VBA, because then you get this:

> ```
> Private Property Get ITransactionRecord_TRANSACTION_DATE() As Date
> ```

And VBA gets confused with the two underscores, it was only expecting one; in VBA a member that implements an interface member (or handles an event source's events) would be a private method named `[Source]_[MemberName]`: the `_` underscore character has a syntactical meaning in an interface member's signature, it should be used carefully if at all, at least in any class that means to be implemented by others.

Rename your the property to *PascalCase* `TransactionDate`, and the problem goes away:

```
Public Property Get TransactionDate() As Date
End Property
```

```
Private Property Get ITransactionRecord_TransactionDate() As Date
```