# VBA: Is it possible to create/define a class as a specific instead of another, existing class?

Tags: vba, excel, class

I am wondering if, in VBA, it's possible to define and create a class object that is a specific instance of another, existing class object.  For example, I would like to create a class called SpecialWorkbook which has properties specific to a unique workbook (class) in my directory. These properties would include Path, Name, FullName (Path & Name), Password, etc.

I know it would be possible to access all of the properties of the Application.Workbook class --

```
With Application.Workbooks(SpecialWorkbook.Name)
```

-- but that route may seem unintuitive to a user since the SpecialWorkbook class does not have the properties and methods of a standard Workbook class.

Would it be possible to do something like:

```
'In Class Module "SpecialWorkbook"

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Dim SpecialWorkbook as Workbook

    Set SpecialWorkbook = Application.Workbook("SpecialFileName.xlsx")

End Sub
```

And then use it like:

```
'In Standard Module

SpecialWorkbook.sheets.count
```

The above "for instance" obviously doesn't work but that's the general idea I would like to implement if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @c-george: you might want to take a look at [How to use Implements in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373081/how-to-use-the-implements-in-excel-vba/26604768)

Comment: @c-george: and here is the other one: [How to use comparison methods between class object modules in VBA in a similar manner as VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19881863/how-to-use-comparison-methods-between-class-object-modules-in-vba-in-a-similar-m)

Comment: @c-george: and this might also be worthwhile reading: [VBA Class Modules – The Ultimate Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-class-modules/)

Comment: You are conflating *class* and *object*. An object is an *instance* of a class. A class is a *blueprint* for an object; its only purpose is to define the *shape*, i.e. the *interface* of the object. An object can only ever exists at run-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible and it's not really needed.  I only want to refer to one specific object, not multiple instances thereof.  Therefore, I just need a wrapper:

```
Sub test()

    Debug.Print SpecialWorkbook.Name
    Debug.Print SpecialWorkbook.Sheets.Count

End Sub

Function SpecialWorkbook() As Workbook

    Set SpecialWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\mybook.xlsx")
    
End Function
```

This assumes that "C:\Temp\mybook.xlsx" exists and is my SpecialWorkbook.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is static class.

For it to work, you need to make just one change. Say, you have this class called `SpecialWorkbook`:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_workbook_path As String

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    m_workbook_path = "C:\Temp\static_class\mybook.xlsx"
End Sub

Public Property Get Path() As String
    Path = m_workbook_path
End Property
```

1. You need to remove this class with exporting (Remove SpecialWorkbook -> Yes -> Select location).
2. Open SpecialWorkbook.cls in any text editor and change `Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False` to `Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True`.
3. Save changes and import this class module back.

Now you can use it this way:

```
Sub F()
    MsgBox SpecialWorkbook.Path
End Sub
```

Add other properties and methods you need.

Comment: This is good info, and I see how it helps, but it's not the solution I was looking for.  Thanks all the same!