# Errors adding items to a VBA/VB6 Collection

Tags: vba, collections, vb6, excel, ms-office

I'm still learning VBA and I can't figure out wth I'm having so many problems with a Collections object.

I have a function that adds custom objects (I created a very simple class to store some data) that does the typical "read data, create object representation, stick it into Collections" sort of stuff.

If I try to add a "key" to the bag.add call I get a "Compile error. Expected:=" message.

If I don't it appears to have worked then when I run the program it says "Compile Error. Argument not optional" and highlights the "getRevColumns = bag" line.

I can't for the life of me figure out wth is going on! I suspect something wrong with how I initialized my bag?! PS: columnMap is the name of my custom class.

```
Function getRevColumns() As Collection

Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim bag As Collection
Dim opManCol As Integer, siebelCol As Integer
Dim opManColName As String, siebelColName As String
Dim itm As columnMap

Set bag = New Collection
Set rng = shSiebelMap.UsedRange.Columns(5)

i = 1
For i = 1 To rng.Rows.count

    If StrComp(UCase(rng.Cells(i).value), "Y") = 0 Then

        opManCol = rng.Rows(i).OffSet(0, -2).value
        opManColName = rng.Rows(i).OffSet(0, -4)
        siebelCol = rng.Rows(i).OffSet(0, -1).value
        siebelColName = rng.Rows(i).OffSet(0, -3)

        Set itm = New columnMap
        itm.opManColName = opManColName
        itm.opManColNumber = opManCol
        itm.siebelColName = siebelColName
        itm.siebelColNumber = siebelCol

        'WHY DOESN'T IT WORK!''
        bag.Add (itm)

        'MsgBox "opMan Col: " & opManColName & " : " & opManCol & ". Siebel Col: " & siebelColName & " : " & siebelCol'

    End If

Next i

getRevColumns = bag

End Function
```

Comment: Is it possible that you post the class "columnMap" also, please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try removing the parens around itm in the add:

```
bag.Add itm
```

or

```
bag.Add itm, key
```

It's been a while since I've had to work with VBA/VB6, but I believe including the parens causes itm to be passed by value instead of by reference. I could be wrong.

Comment: One word: Bizzare!

Thanks a million mate. I'm still getting errors but now it's something else.

Comment: This behavior was also discussed in the Question `Hidden features of VBA` on StackOverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070863/hidden-features-of-vba#1070942

Answer (score 3):

the bag is an object. Rule #1 for objects use Set

```
Set getRevColumns = bag
```

Comment: Yep you were definitely right there! Weird weird VBA... Where's the return keyword?!

Comment: There is no explicit return statement. The return value(or object as in your case) has to match the name of the function.

Comment: Yep I got that after 20 minutes of scratching my head and an additional 10 of googling!

Answer (score 0):

You need to say

```
set getRevColumns = bag
```

also I guess you have a problem on the add. I don't know why this is but it works on

```
bag.add itm
```

I tried the whole thing in a simple manner here is my working code

```
Sub myroutine()

     Dim bag As Collection
     Dim itm As clsSimple

     Set bag = getTheCollection()

     Set itm = bag.Item(1)
     MsgBox (itm.someObjectValue)

     Set itm = bag.Item(2)
     MsgBox (itm.someObjectValue)


End Sub

Function getTheCollection() As Collection

        Dim bag As Collection
        Dim itm As clsSimple

        Set bag = New Collection

        Set itm = New clsSimple
        itm.someObjectValue = "value 1"
        bag.Add itm

        Set itm = New clsSimple
        itm.someObjectValue = "value 2"
        bag.Add itm

        Set getTheCollection = bag

End Function
```

The class is really simple:

```
Public someObjectValue As String
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It definitely does mate! Can't understand why I'm not supposed to use () around that add method... but anyway as long as it works.

Comment: Yes is crazy but as Vincent mentioned before there seems to be some logic behind it how the parameter is passed (by value or by reference). I googled it for a while but couldn't find anything. VBA is somehow old VB6 and wasn't perfect.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem with a collection.

I Dim'd it but hadn't set it with New or initialized it.

Basically i had

```
Dim collection1 As Collection
...
collection1.Add item     'no compile error just empty
```

I added the following before the add

```
Set collection1 = New Collection
Call collection1.init
```

then it worked like a charm...I had also moved the Dim statement from the Sub to the top of the Module to make it a class variable