# Writing a VLOOKUP function in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to lookup a value on a spreadsheet within a table array using the VLOOKUP function in my vba code.  I don't know how to write it correctly.

Here is the normal VLOOKUP formula with all the references:

```
=VLOOKUP(DATA!AN2,DATA!AA9:AF20,5,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
Dim result As String 
Dim sheet As Worksheet 
Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data") 
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sheet.Range("AN2"), sheet.Range("AA9:AF20"), 5, False)
```

Comment: If the lookup fails it will throw an error: however if you drop the "WorksheetFunction" it will not, but you can test the outcome using IsError(result).  You'd need to declare result as variant though.

Answer (score 18):

How about just using:

```
result = [VLOOKUP(DATA!AN2, DATA!AA9:AF20, 5, FALSE)]
```

Note the **[** and **]**.

Comment: The information above is based upon this answer -> [Hidden features of vba](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070863/hidden-features-of-vba)

Comment: What if you need part of this statement to be dynamic?  For example, the AF20 could be AF99 or AF10.  Normally with a string, you could use something like:  "VLOOKUP(DATA!AN2, DATA!AA9:AF" & lastrow & ", 5, FALSE)".  That doesn't seem to work when using the square brackets.

Comment: @Noah I think the accepted answer is what you need if you have something dynamic in mind.

Answer (score 7):

Please find the code below for `Vlookup`:

```
Function vlookupVBA(lookupValue, rangeString, colOffset)
vlookupVBA = "#N/A"
On Error Resume Next
Dim table_lookup As range
Set table_lookup = range(rangeString)
vlookupVBA = Application.WorksheetFunction.vlookup(lookupValue, table_lookup, colOffset, False)
End Function
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me as the VLOOKUP issues bothers me couple hours. This also works for lookup up on other sheet, thanks for the sharing!

Answer (score 2):

As [Tim Williams suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567513/writing-a-vlookup-function-in-vba#comment6340191_5567608), using `Application.VLookup` will not throw an error if the lookup value is not found (unlike `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup`).

If you want the lookup to return a default value when it fails to find a match, and to avoid hard-coding the column number -- an equivalent of `IFERROR(VLOOKUP(what, where, COLUMNS(where), FALSE), default)` in formulas, you could use the following function:

```
Private Function VLookupVBA(what As Variant, lookupRng As Range, defaultValue As Variant) As Variant
    Dim rv As Variant: rv = Application.VLookup(what, lookupRng, lookupRng.Columns.Count, False)
    If IsError(rv) Then
        VLookupVBA = defaultValue
    Else
        VLookupVBA = rv
    End If
End Function

Public Sub UsageExample()
    MsgBox VLookupVBA("ValueToFind", ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ReferenceSheet").Range("A:D"), "Not found!")
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim found As Integer
    found = 0

    Dim vTest As Variant

    vTest = Application.VLookup(TextBox1.Value, _
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A2:A55"), 1, False)

If IsError(vTest) Then
    found = 0
    MsgBox ("Type Mismatch")
    TextBox1.SetFocus
    Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
Else

    TextBox2.Value = Application.VLookup(TextBox1.Value, _
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A2:B55"), 2, False)
    found = 1
    End If
```

Answer (score -2):

```
        Public Function VLOOKUP1(ByVal lookup_value As String, ByVal table_array As Range, ByVal col_index_num As Integer) As String
        Dim i As Long

        For i = 1 To table_array.Rows.Count
            If lookup_value = table_array.Cells(table_array.Row + i - 1, 1) Then
                VLOOKUP1 = table_array.Cells(table_array.Row + i - 1, col_index_num)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i

        End Function
```