# Trying to automatically split data in excel with vba

Tags: windows, excel, vba

I have absolutely no experience programming in excel vba other than I wrote a function to add a data stamp to a barcode that was scanned in on our production line a few weeks back, mainly through trial and error.

Anyways, what I need help with right now is inventory is coming up and every item we have has a barcode and is usually scanned into notepad and then manually pulled into excel and "text to columns" is used. I found the excel split function and would like a little bit of help getting it to work with my scanned barcodes.

The data comes in in the format: 11111*A153333*11/30/11 plus a carriage return , where the * would be the delimiter. All the examples I've found don't seem to do anything, at all.

For example here is one I found on splitting at the " ", but nothing happens if I change it to *.

```
Sub splitText()

'splits Text active cell using * char as separator
Dim splitVals As Variant
Dim totalVals As Long

splitVals = Split(ActiveCell.Value, "*")
totalVals = UBound(splitVals)

Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1 + totalVals)).Value = splitVals
End Sub
```

And this is applied in the Sheet1 code section, if that helps.

It really can't be this complicated, can it?

Edit: Trying to add in Vlookup to the vba.

So as I said below in the comments, I'm now working on getting the vlookup integrated into this, however it just returns N/A.

Here is the sub I wrote based on the link below

```
Public Sub vlook(ByRef codeCell As Range)
Dim result As String
Dim source As Worksheet
Dim destination As Worksheet
Set destination = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory")
Set source = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Descriptions")

result = [Vlookup(destination!(codeCell.Row, D), source!A2:B1397, 2, FALSE)]
End Sub
```

And I was trying to call it right after the For loop in the worksheet change, and just created another for loop, does this/should this be a nested for loop?

Comment: I've just run your code against the test string you specified and it worked fine - filled the next three cells with the split values.

Comment: Where did you put the code? Maybe that's my problem? I put the code into the sheet1 code. When I open it up (Alt+F11) I just paste that little Sub in there and when I scan with my barcode scanner, it does nothing but newline down to the next row.

Comment: You need to either *run* the code (for example, as a macro), or create some sort of worksheet function based on the logic.

Comment: Alright so going off of phoog's comment I changed the sub to 
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range) which didn't work, but if i choose the Worksheet_SelectionChange() it works when I select the column. What the hell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding the code to the VBA behind the worksheet won't actually cause it to get called. You need to handle the worksheet_change event. The following should help:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Target.Cells
        If cell.Column = 1 Then SplitText cell
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Public Sub SplitText(ByRef codeCell As Range)

    'splits Text active cell using * char as separator
    Dim splitVals As Variant
    Dim totalVals As Long

    splitVals = Split(codeCell.Value, "*")
    totalVals = UBound(splitVals)

    Range(Cells(codeCell.Row, codeCell.Column), Cells(codeCell.Row, codeCell.Column + totalVals)).Value = splitVals

End Sub
```

Comment: Jon, that works just as I wanted, well almost. Any quick edits to not leave the bar code in the first column? So that 15242*A133401*11/30/13 becomes 15242, but the rest carries over to the next columns?

Comment: See amended code above. The `Statis inProgress` is there to stop everything looping (as you're editing column 1 again).

Comment: Thank you sir, that will do it!

Comment: So logically moving forward, they now want to add a Vlookup description look-up, which i can do any day of the week, but it doesn't want to work at all with the vba enabled. Is there a trick to getting it to work? Right now it just returns #N/A, and I'm assuming it's because it's doing the look-up on the actual bar code and not the stripped down value. I tried searching on here, and did find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567513/writing-a-vlookup-function-in-vba) but can't get it to play nice with the other function. Thanks again

Comment: An alternative to using a Static Boolean to stop the endless loop of updates is to add the line ``Application.EnableEvents = False`` at the beginning of the ``Worksheet_Change`` procedure and then to turn events back on at the end.

Comment: @Rachel Any benefit in doing it this way over the static bool?

Comment: The net effect is the same. I think preventing the Change event from running in the first place is preferable--you just need to make sure the events get turned back on. FWIW @TimWilliam's version avoids this issue by running the code within the event procedure; the only downside is if you wanted to call the SplitText procedure from anywhere else.

Comment: @RachelHettinger: Good point. Didn't know about that setting. Will update the code for the sake of having a preferred solution listed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to process the barcodes automatically on entering them, you need something like this (goes in the worksheet module).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim splitVals As Variant
Dim c As Range, val As String

    For Each c In Target.Cells

        If c.Column = 1 Then 'optional: only process barcodes if in ColA
            val = Trim(c.Value)
            If InStr(val, "*") > 0 Then
                splitVals = Split(val, "*")
                c.Offset(0, 1).Resize( _
                   1, (UBound(splitVals) - LBound(splitVals)) + 1 _
                                       ).Value = splitVals
            End If
        End If 'in ColA

    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: I think the reference to ``ActiveCell.Value`` needs to be changed to ``val``.