# If,IsError,VLOOKUP syntax error - anyone know why?

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a syntax error on this statement below that combines an If, IsError and VLOOKUP statement - I been trying everything..... anyone know why?

```
If Application.Worksheetfunction.IsError(VLOOKUP(cell.Value,'[Codes.xlsx]Processing Codes'!ProcessingCodesTable,5,FALSE)) = FALSE then
```

Thanks any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VLOOKUP [is not](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/index_vba.php) a VBA function.

The previous question "[Writing a VLOOKUP function in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567513/writing-a-vlookup-function-in-vba)" offers multiple ways of getting around this. It looks like you can just use `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` in place of `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: Thanks I have corrected this, but I believe there is also an error with my table array syntax because if I were to replace it with a static range such as "A1:A15" the error goes away.

Comment: @user3242388 Whatever the range for ProcessingCodesTable is, you are asking to return the 5th column in that range

Comment: Isn't your '[Codes.xlsx]Processing Codes'!ProcessingCodesTable a named range not a VBA variable, so needs to be in double quotes too?

Comment: yes ProcessingCodesTable is a named range in an external workbook, I have never seen an example of referencing it in double quotes?  what would the syntax be to reference a named ranged in an external workbook?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to adapt something like this

```
Sub lookupPC()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Dim result As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Processing Codes")
For Each cell In Range("a1:a100")
  If IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell.Value, ws.Range("ProcessingCodesTable"), 5, False)) = False Then
    result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell.Value, ws.Range("ProcessingCodesTable"), 5, False)
  End If
 MsgBox (result)
Next cell
ErrHandler:
 MsgBox (cell.Address & " value not available in table")
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually the IsError function maybe should be left out and just do error handling yourself if there isn't a valid vlookup value