# How to apply vlookup formula in blank cells only

Tags: excel, vba

I want to apply vlookup formula only in those blank cells B4, B7, B10.  I want to write macro so that vlookup formula applies only to the blank cells, rest of the data remain intact.

[VLOOKUPFORMULA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecStb.png)

Comment: Hi there, could you not just add another column and use `IF($B1="",VLOOKUP(),"")`? or must the answer be in the same column using VBA? if so can you provide the code that you have tried so far please? This is not a coding service but a forum to help people with their learning. Thank you.

Comment: What's the vlookup formula? (it's different in VBA)

Comment: To piggyback @Glitch_Doctor, If you are unsure how to ask, check out [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I would advise reading [Writing a VLOOKUP function in vba](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567513/writing-a-vlookup-function-in-vba) it covers how the WorksheetFunction property works and reseach how to use a `for each` loop. That is all you will need to achieve what you have set out for. Edit - use an if statement with the for each cell in range to find the blank cells then apply the vlookup, you can even then copy the cell and pastespecial values if you do not want the formula in there