# VBA lookup and return text in different column

Tags: excel, vba, lookup

I'm working on a list of tasks where i have a status column (H) and a deadline column (J) around 1000 rows. Starting from row 7

If a task gets the state "Closed" the date in the same row but in the deadline column should be over written with the text "Done"

Of cause I could do "If" and "Then" commands for each row but the code will be soooo long. Thinking of the Lookup function that could be a fast and simple way of doing this but I'm not that familiar with the Lookup function. Any help would be appreciated.

I have attached a picture for better understanding.

Thanks in advance
/Martin

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a [VLOOKUP in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567513/writing-a-vlookup-function-in-vba)?

Comment: Yes I'm quite sure the VBA VLOOKUP could do the job.. I'm currently reading and learning about the function and tomorrow i will try creating some code. .

Comment: If you want to replace a date(?) in Col J with "Done" based on ColH then likely you'd want to use something like the worksheet_change event for that.  Doesn't seem like VLOOKUP is applicable here?   There's no screenshot in your post.

Comment: Ups, forgot the picture, but now it's there..

Comment: And yes, if for example H7 is "Closed" the date in J7 should be over written with "Done" But of cause there could be several of closed tasks in the list, therefore i'm looking for a way to look through the entire column

Comment: Is your data in a Table/ListObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Run `InitialUpdate` once first to update all column J data.

```vb
Sub InitialUpdate()
    Dim rngData  As Range, arrData
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngData = ActiveSheet.Cells(7, "H").Resize(lastRow - 7 + 1, 3)
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrData)
        If UCase(arrData(i, 1)) = "CLOSED" Then
            arrData(i, 3) = "Done"
        End If
    Next
    ' Disable change event
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    rngData.Value = arrData
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Step 2: Implement `Worksheet_Change` which handles ongoing daily inputs.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range, rngData  As Range, arrData
    Dim cell As Range
    Set c = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("H"))
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each cell In c
           If UCase(cell.Value) = "CLOSED" Then
                cell.Offset(0, 2) = "Done"
            End If
        Next
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Note: `Worksheet_Change` can validate the whole column H each input. I prefer to use `InitialUpdate` optimizes bulk update.