# Calling a Sub in VBA

Tags: vba, syntax-error, call

This my simplified script:

```
    Sub SomeOtherSub(Stattyp As String)
        'Daty and the other variables are defined here

        CatSubProduktAreakum(Stattyp, Daty + UBound(SubCategories) + 2)

    End Sub

    Sub CatSubProduktAreakum(Stattyp As String, starty As Integer)

    'some stuff

    End Sub
```

The call of CatSubProduktAreakum is marked red as a "syntax error". I don't understand the error. It is a simple sub-routine call with two arguments. Why does VBA not accept the call?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Try -

```
Call CatSubProduktAreakum(Stattyp, Daty + UBound(SubCategories) + 2)
```

As for the reason, this from MSDN via this question - [What does the Call keyword do in VB6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479891/what-does-the-call-keyword-do-in-vb6)

> You are not required to use the Call keyword when calling a procedure.
>   However, if you use the Call keyword to call a procedure that requires
>   arguments, argumentlist must be enclosed in parentheses. If you omit
>   the Call keyword, you also must omit the parentheses around
>   argumentlist. If you use either Call syntax to call any intrinsic or
>   user-defined function, the function's return value is discarded.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. If I call the Sub-routine with only one argument (and define it with only one argument), then I can call it just by its name (and the argument in parenthesis). Why is it not possible to just call a Sub with two arguments?

Comment: @reggie You can call a sub without Call as long as you skip the brackets `Mysub arg1,arg2,arg3` However, you need to read up on ByVal and ByRef.

Comment: ... for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070863/hidden-features-of-vba

Comment: and this is why i hate VBA.

Answer (score 13):

For anyone still coming to this post, the other option is to simply omit the parentheses:

```
Sub SomeOtherSub(Stattyp As String)
    'Daty and the other variables are defined here

    CatSubProduktAreakum Stattyp, Daty + UBound(SubCategories) + 2

End Sub
```

The `Call` keywords is only really in VBA for backwards compatibilty and isn't actually required.

**If** however, you decide to use the `Call` keyword, then you have to change your syntax to suit.

```
'// With Call
Call Foo(Bar)

'// Without Call
Foo Bar
```

Both will do exactly the same thing.

---

That being said, there may be instances to watch out for where using parentheses unnecessarily will cause things to be evaluated where you didn't intend them to be (as parentheses do this in VBA) so with that in mind the better option is probably to omit the `Call` keyword and the parentheses