# multiple argument subs vba

Tags: vba, arguments, call

Using VBA with Access 2010, I have a sub:

```
Public Sub setInterest(account As String, dmonth As Integer)
    ...somecode...
End Sub
```

And I am calling it with

```
setInterest("myAccount",3)
```

And I get syntax errors.
Modifying the sub to only take one argument and leaving out the 3 gives no errors, the problem is only when I have 2 arguments.

Comment: duplicate of [Calling a Sub in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715044/calling-a-sub-in-vba)... and many others. This issue has been answered multiple times already.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

When using multiple arguments, you can either write:

```
 setInterest "myAccount", 3
```

Or

```
 Call setInterest("myAccount", 3)
```

In both examples you can name the arguments:

```
setInterest account:="myAccount", dmonth:= 3
```

Answer (score 2):

I add this answer, for **Why your syntax works with one argument ?**

```
Public Sub setInterest(account As String)
    '...somecode...
End Sub

setInterest ("myAccount")
```

> **Note :**
>   When there is not any `,` between `(` and `)`, VBA thinks it's a *formula* and exactly one argument.

When formula calculate the result will be like this:

```
Dim str As String
str = ("TEST")
Debug.Print str

[Output:]
TEST
```