# ms access module to add attachment from button

Tags: ms-access, module, cdo.message

I am having the following code in a module, which it is send email with attachment to user.

```
Public Sub EmailToUser()

Dim mail    As Object           ' CDO.MESSAGE
Dim config  As Object           ' CDO.Configuration

Set mail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set config = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

    config.Fields(cdoSendUsingMethod).Value = cdoSendUsingPort
    config.Fields(cdoSMTPServer).Value = "my smtp server"
    config.Fields(cdoSMTPServerPort).Value = 465
    config.Fields(cdoSMTPConnectionTimeout).Value = 10
    config.Fields(cdoSMTPUseSSL).Value = "true"
    config.Fields(cdoSMTPAuthenticate).Value = cdoBasic
    config.Fields(cdoSendUserName).Value = "e=mail"
    config.Fields(cdoSendPassword).Value = "password"
    config.Fields.Update

Set mail.Configuration = config

With mail
    .To = "e-mail"
    .From = "e-mail"
    .Subject = "subject"
    .AddAttachment strPathReport & FileName '<== My question.
    .Send
End With

Set config = Nothing
Set mail = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have a form with 8buttons and each button is send an email with an attachment.
Now, I have in my module 8 times the same code with different attachment.

Is it possible to have only one time the above code and from the button to add the attachment?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you want to add parameters to the procedure. And then pass in the e-mail address, etc.  as arguments.

This question should give you some ideas on how to do that: [multiple argument subs vba](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10152306/685)