# Call a function from sub in vba

Tags: excel, vba, function

I wrote this function, which is supposed to take the user defined cell from a chosen range and add or multiply its value by an user defined number. The output should be an array with one changed cell.

I was able to compile it; however, I cannot call it.

I tried to replicate what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072075/how-do-i-call-a-vba-function-into-a-sub-procedure) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763112/excel-vba-calling-sub-from-another-sub-with-multiple-inputs-outputs-of-differen) but it failed.

```
Function Macro1(cellref As Range, row_number As Long, column_number As Long, x As Double, method As Integer) As Variant
'Number, which will be added or multiplied by chosen cell value in an array
'One for multiplication, two for addition
  If method = 1 Then
    Cells(row_number, column_number) = Cells(row_number, column_number) * x
  ElseIf method = 2 Then 
    Cells(row_number, column_number) = Cells(row_number, column_number) + x
  End If
  Result = Macro1
End Function

Sub try()
  Macro1(Range("A1:AX3").Select, 2, 2, 0.5, 1) = Result
End Sub
```

When running this code, I get the error message "Run-time error 424, object required". The line `Macro1(Range("A1:AX3").Select, 2, 2, 0.5, 1) = Result` gets red highlighted

Then I tried

```
Function Macro1(cellref As Range, row_number As Long, column_number As Long, x As Double, method As Integer) As Variant
'Number, which will be added or multiplied by chosen cell value in an array
'One for multiplication, two for addition
  If method = 1 Then
    Cells(row_number, column_number) = Cells(row_number, column_number) * x
  ElseIf method = 2 Then 
    Cells(row_number, column_number) = Cells(row_number, column_number) + x
  End If
  Result = Macro1
End Function

Sub try()
  Macro1(Worksheets("Macro1").Range("A1:AX3"), 2, 2, 0.5, 1)
End Sub
```

But I got "Type mismatch Error 13" message. The line `Sub try()` is highlighted in yellow and the line below it is red

Comment: In `Cells(row_number, column_number) * "x"` the `"x"` is a text not a variable. Change it to `Cells(row_number, column_number) * x` same for `+ "x"`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ done, but I still get the same error messages

Comment: Please tell in wich lines you get the errors.

Comment: `Range("A1:AX3").Select` should just be changed to `Range("A1:AX3")` That function is asking for a `Range` type to be passed to it. Instead you are passing whatever the output of the `.Select` method is of the range (a Variant, not a Range) instead of just passing the range itself. So: `Macro1(Range("A1:AX3"), 2, 2, 0.5, 1) = Result`

Comment: Where do you use `Result` and why do you have a `Variant` return type for you function if you do not set a return value?

Comment: @JNevill works now. But it changes the current array. The ideal output would be producing another array with one changed value and keeping the original array for comparison.

Comment: In this code, what is the "Original Array". You are calling a function and getting nothing back from the function. `Result = Macro1` makes no sense as `Result` a variable that you don't declare is being set to nothing as `Macro1` is never set in it's function. I don't see any arrays here just manipulations to cells and ranges. I believe there are layers of misunderstandings here.

Comment: @JNevill the original array is Range("A1:AX3"). This function is supposed to copy this array somewhere else in the sheet and change the value of one cell.

Comment: I see. The problem is that your function isn't using the range you pass to it and you are just monkeying around with `Cells` in the function which is just referencing the cells in your `ActiveSheet`. Essentially this isn't doing anything like what you describe. I think maybe taking a step back and writing this in a single `sub` and verifying your logic works like you want it to will help a ton. Then you can break out the individual function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see several issues:

**First**, the line

```
Result = Macro1
```

In `Macro1` is a recursive call to `Macro1`. i.e. `Macro1` is trying to call itself.

You'll get an error because `Macro1` requires parameters, the first of which is an `Object` (a `Range` is an `Object`), and you're not supplying an object parameter. As a matter of fact, you're not supplying *any* required parameters in this call.

---

**Second**, the code:

```
<functionName> = value
```

Is backwards. That line is attempting to set `Macro1` (the `<functionName>` on the left-hand side of the assignment operator `=`) to the value of `Result`. This isn't possible (at least not in in VBA). I believe that what you want is:

```
result = Macro1(Worksheets("Macro1").Range("A1:AX3"), 2, 2, 0.5, 1)
```

Which will execute `Macro1` with the specified parameters, then assign the returned value (a `Variant` as you've defined it) to the `Variant` variable (because you haven't `Dim`med it) `result`.

---

**Third**, you've declared `Macro1` to be a `Function`, but there's no need to - it's *not* returning a value, it's setting cells in the `Range` it's been passed. You'd be best served by changing this to a `Sub`, since that's the kind of work it's doing. I think you may have been intending to have it return a value with the line `Result = Macro1`, but as mentioned, that ain't gonna do it. VBA works by assigning the value to be returned to the `Function` name, not with a `return` function as some other languages do. If you do have some sort of result you want to return, you'd assign it with the code:

```
Macro1 = <the value to be returned>
```

However, I'm not sure what you'd actually be returning from this as a `Function` because it can work on a `Range` not an individual `Cell`

---

**Fourth**, I'm not entirely certain why you're accepting a whole `Range` as the parameter to `Macro1`, then specifying a single `Cell` within it. Passing in `...Range("A1:AX3")`, then specifying I want `column 2` and `Row 2` of that range is *way* too much cognitive effort to sort out what cell you're after. Why not just pass in `...Range("B2")` and be done with it? The benefits are

1) `Macro1` works directly with the desired cell and the desired cell only

2) The caller specifies the desired cell and the desired cell only

3) You eliminate otherwise unnecessary parameters from the param list.

---

**Fifth** your `Macro1` receives a `Range` parameter to work on, but never references it. You accept `cellref As Range`, but in the code body, you're working with `Cells()` and never once reference `cellref`. There are a couple of issues with this:

1) You have an unspecified `Cells()` which will automatically reference the `ActiveSheet`, whether that's your intent or not.

2) You're *not* at all working with whatever it is that you're passing in when you call `Macro1` (which could be on *any* `Worksheet` in the `Workbook`).

You have done a great job of being very specific in your call *to* `Macro1` by specifying `Worksheets("Macro1").Range("A1:AX3")` so that VBA knows *exactly* what cell you're after. However, if you happen to be looking at `Sheet2` at the time of the call, `Macro1` will be working with `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2")` because at this point `Activesheet` = `Worksheets("Sheet2")` instead of `Worksheets("Macro1")`.

---

**Sixth** you're doing no sanity checking on your input values. What happens if the value in the passed cell happens to be `red` instead of `17.256`. What's the value of `red * 2`? Why, it's a `Runtime error #13. Type mismatch`. You need some sort of sanity checking or error handling to ensure you're working with numeric data.

---

In the end, I would suggest something like this with a pre-execution sanity check:

```
Function Macro1(cellref As Range, x As Double, method As Long) As Variant
'Number, which will be added or multiplied by chosen cell value in an array
'One for multiplication, two for addition

  Dim Result As Double

  If Not IsNumeric(cellref.Value) Then
    MsgBox ("The cell does not contain a numeric value")
    Exit Function
  End If

  If method = 1 Then
    Result = cellref.Value * x
  ElseIf method = 2 Then
    Result = cellref.Value + x
  End If
  Macro1 = Result

End Function

Sub try()
  With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("B2") = Macro1(.Range("B2"), 0.5, 1)
  End With
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could go with error handling and do it like this:

```
Option Explicit

Function Macro1(cellref As Range, x As Double, method As Long) As Variant
'Number, which will be added or multiplied by chosen cell value in an array
'One for multiplication, two for addition

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

  Dim Result As Double

  If method = 1 Then
    Result = cellref.Value * x
  ElseIf method = 2 Then
    Result = cellref.Value + x
  End If

CleanExit:
  Macro1 = Result

ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox ("The cell does not contain a numeric value")
  Result = vbNull
  Resume CleanExit

End Function

Sub try()
  With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("B2") = Macro1(.Range("B2"), 0.5, 1)
  End With
End Sub
```

Notice the inclusion of `Option Explicit` that requires that you declare (`Dim`) *all* variables before you use them. This will help eliminate other potential errors where you misspell `Variable1` as `Varaible1` and VBA "helpfully" creates a whole new variable for you creating a very difficult bug to find.

---

Based on some of the other comments, I *think* that you are attempting to call this for many cells in a range. If that's the case, you can add some simple looping to the `Try()` procedure to run through all the cells that this needs to be applied to. If not, and you're somehow trying to apply this to one cell in a `Range` based on other values in that range, you'll need to modify some portion of it to do what you're after. I hope there's enough info in this post for you to figure out how to do that. If not, that would probably make for a great follow up question once you've fully grokked what's going on in changing this one cell.

---

As a side note, there is a great OSS VBE add-on called [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduckvba.com/) which will help you find and fix a lot of these types of errors. I'm a great fan of the tool, I use it daily, and I've contributed to the project as well.

Comment: Glad you found it helpful, @Maria

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need the cellref parameter you aren't using it.

as @nacorid and @Jnevill said result = Macro1 doesn't do anything, the code just skips it. If you want a return on your function it would be Macro1 = result. However, you don't assign anything to result so it still won't do anything. You would also need to create an assignment in `sub try()` to capture the return.

I am not sure what you mean by your expected output is an array with one changed cell, You are changing a cell but it isn't an array you are just directly changing the value of it with this line: `Cells(row_number, column_number) = Cells(row_number, column_number) * x`

Edit:
Here is how you load up an array, modify and paste it somewhere else.

You will need to add some error handling to not get type mismatches.

You may also want to make it a little more dynamic with an offset number for the pasterange.

```
sub macro1()
    Dim rngarr() As Variant
    Dim divisor As Double
    Dim targetcol As Long
    Dim targetrow As Long
    Dim pasterange As Range

    rngarr = Range("A1:AX3").Value
    'Remember that your array starts at index 1
    'A range that starts at row 2 will still have an index 1
    targetcol = 2
    targetrow = 2

    divisor = 0.5

    rngarr(targetrow, targetcol) = rngarr(targetrow, targetcol) * divisor

    Set pasterange = Range("A5:AX7")

    pasterange = rngarr
end sub
```

Comment: I am changing a cell, that is true, but this cell is in an array of cells, where each of them has a value. Expected output= whole array with all the original values and one changed value

Comment: then you need to assign the cell values to an array, modify the value using the index in the array of the cell you want to change, then return the array. If you are trying to then paste the new value with the rest of the array you need to dump the array into a new range.

Comment: that is exactly what I meant and tried (and failed) to do. Could you please specify it?