# Syntax Error with MsgBox

Tags: excel, vba

This results in a syntax error:

```
Sub test()
    MsgBox("hello world", vbOKCancel) ' syntax error at this line
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a Sub in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715044/calling-a-sub-in-vba)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett You should have come earlier. I mean the question is answered and the answer is a very good one. Way better than the one from the duplicate question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're just using the `MsgBox` method as a `Sub`. In VB6/VBA a `Sub` call either doesn't use brackets, or uses the `Call` keyword.

```
MsgBox "hello world", vbOKCancel

or

Call MsgBox("hello world", vbOKCancel)
```

The brackets come into play when using the method as a function (ie you want the return value)

```
Dim msgResult

msgResult = MsgBox("hello world", vbOKCancel)
```

I would guess that, since you're using `vbOKCancel`, this is the version you'll end up using to find out what the user clicked.

Comment: The syntax of VBA makes me startle every time!

Comment: @mini-me: Yup - Its got plenty of "character"!

Comment: Parentheses, not brackets.