# Argument not optional with Collection

Tags: vba

I checked other similar questions but most of the time it was a "set" which was forgotten. I don't think i forgot one so that's why i'm asking.

I have this module :

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Public AssetFamilyCollection As New Collection
Public AssetCollection As New Collection


Sub test_demarrage()

    Dim wsTest As Worksheet
    Dim paf As ProcessAssetFamily
    Dim fmly As AssetFamily
    Dim i As Integer

    Set wsTest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test")

    Set AssetFamilyCollection = CreateAssetFamilyCollection()
    Set AssetCollection = CreateAssetCollection()
    Set paf = New ProcessAssetFamily
    Set paf.AssetFamilyCollection = AssetFamilyCollection
    paf.DefaultValue
    paf.CountAssetByFamily (AssetCollection)

End Sub
```

The error is one the line `paf.CountAssetByFamily (AssetCollection)`

Here is the code of the class ProcessAssetFamily

```
Option Explicit

Private pAssetFamilyCollection As Collection

'Get Set for the collection of AssetFamily
Public Property Get AssetFamilyCollection() As Collection
    Set AssetFamilyCollection = pAssetFamilyCollection
End Property

Public Property Set AssetFamilyCollection(lAssetFamilyCollection As Collection)
    Set pAssetFamilyCollection = lAssetFamilyCollection
End Property

Public Sub DefaultValue()

    Dim fmly As AssetFamily
    For Each fmly In AssetFamilyCollection
            fmly.checked = False
            fmly.startColumn = 0
    Next fmly

End Sub

Public Sub CountAssetByFamily(CollectionOfAsset As Collection)

    Dim asst As Asset
    Dim fmly As AssetFamily
    Dim sum As Integer

    fmly.numberOfAsset = 0

    For Each fmly In Me

        fmly.numberOfAsset

        For Each asst In CollectionOfAsset
            If asst.familyName = fmly.name Then
                fmly.numberOfAsset = fmly.numberOfAsset + 1
            End If
        Next asst

    Next fmly


End Sub
```

Comment: `CreateAssetCollection()` is it returning a collection?

Comment: Call it without parenthesis like this `paf.CountAssetByFamily AssetCollection`. Check [how to call sub in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715044/calling-a-sub-in-vba).

Comment: @cyboashu yes it is !

Comment: Not sure to understand how you defined `ProcessAssetFamily` in the 2nd code. How come `ProcessAssetFamily` is not mentioned at all in it ?

Comment: @dee thanks it enters the sub but now i have "object doesnt support this property or method" on the line `For Each fmly In Me`

Comment: @Seb i don't understand ?

Comment: Maybe `For Each fmly In pAssetFamilyCollection` ?

Comment: @dee it works, i changed Me with AssetFamilyCollection. Why Me doesnt work ?

Comment: `Me` is the class itself and it has no enumerator defined, can't be enumerated. Collections can so I guessed you wanted to enumerate the  collection elements.

Comment: @dee ok got it, thanks !