# Is it good practice to leave "Debug.Print" instructions in code that goes in "production"?

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA, is it good practice to leave `Debug.Print` instructions in code that goes in "production" ? That is quite useful to debug the sheets realtime at the user's machine when something goes wrong. Does it affect performance when Visual Studio is closed ? If not, what would you advise ?

Comment: You say "Visual Studio" but you are talking about VBA, right? Do you mean VBE?

Comment: Ahhh, yes I guess I just understand what people referred to as VBE now... Yes I guess so :)  [ALT + F11]

Comment: 1) If it is important to capture what the user was doing when the things went wrong, a transaction log would seen a better option. Start a new file per run or per day; delete any over 48 hours old.  Yes there is a performance cost but how would you measure it. 2) Visual Studio is MS's development environment for its professional languages.  VB 2010 is hundreds of times faster than VBA/VBE and has thousands of cool facilities.  You can access Excel from it if you want to use a worksheet.

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716276(v=vs.60).aspx , debug.print statements are removed when Visual Basic is compiled.... but unlike VB, VBA is interpreted... (or is it compiled at run-time?), so I'm not sure about that one. I wanna say interpreted, because I can write VBA while at a breakpoint :P

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Debug.Print instruction DO have a small performance cost. So I would avoid them in loops that are executed a zillion times. Except for those cases, I think it's ok to keep them.
You could also use conditional compilation directives (`#if`) in combination with a compiler constant (`#const`) to enable/disable them globally without performance impact.

```
#CONST developMode = True

sub Xyz
  #If developMode Then
    Debug.Print "something"
  #End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @iDevelop +1 Learn something new everyday - didn't realise Excel supported conditional compilation! Thanks.

Comment: Clear enough to desserve a +1 :). Btw, conditional compilation (and some useful other stuff) was discussed in this interesting thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070863/hidden-features-of-vba

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: That's the way I do it, with a global variable of `DebugMode`.  I have a small check on `ThisWorkbook.Save` to flag if `DebugMode` is True, helps stop it sneaking into production.

Comment: @Lunatik: that's fine too, but in regarding performance impact, a global (well any "normal") variable WILL have an impact on performance, while a compiler constant will not (when set to production mode).

Answer (score 4):

I usually have two versions; prod without debugging, and prod with debugging. That, combined with the catchall error handler logging, means that if a user experiences issues, I can deploy the debug version to them and they can run that up.

I have a macro that I run that comments out the debug.print statements, so it's not a real maintenance overhead.

The problem with running a debug version all the time (and, with Excel VBA it's not usually a performance thing) is that your app is constantly emitting information that it doesn't need too. In an environment with controlled spreadsheets, for example, this can be seen as a bad thing.

In terms of global error handling, you still need the On Error GoTo statement for every function you want error handling in. You can, however, pipe these to a common function:

```
Public Function HandleTheNastyErrors(E As ErrObject, ByVal writeLog As Boolean = True) 

    Select Case E.Number 

    Case xxx 

        ...specific error handling... 

    Case Else 
        ... Display a message to the user about how you dont know what happened....             
    End Select 

    If writeLog Then

       ...Log Writing Code...

    End If

End Function
```

And then, OnError:

```
ErrorHandler:
 Call HandleTheNastyErrors(Err, True)
```

Show do the trick

Comment: Could you comment on your "catch all" ? I don't really have ideas of how to handle errors smartly and somehow generically so far. Thanks !

Comment: @jeromeG There you go. Hope it helps.

Comment: passing the error object it self to the functon...that's an interesting idea.