# How to generate a string of random characters from a given list of characters?

Tags: ms-access, vba

How can I generate a string of random characters from a given list of characters?

```vb
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Dim pool As String
    pool = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    Dim count
    count = 0
    result.Text = ""
    Randomize
    Dim cc
    cc As New Rnd
    Dim strpos
    strpos = ""
    While count <= Lengthh.Text
        strpos = cc.Next(0, pool.length)
        result.Text = result.Text & pool(strpos)
        count = count + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like a weird blend of VBA and VB.net

Comment: Take a look [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In VBA `Rnd` is a function, not a class and strings can't be treated as arrays. You need to use the function `Mid` to extract individual characters.

You can write a function to return a random string. The function can then be used by your event-handler:

```
Function RandString(n As Long) As String
    'Assumes that Randomize has been invoked by caller
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, m As Long, s As String, pool As String
    pool = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    m = Len(pool)
    For i = 1 To n
        j = 1 + Int(m * Rnd())
        s = s & Mid(pool, j, 1)
    Next i
    RandString = s
End Function
```

Used like this:

```
Sub test()
    Randomize
    MsgBox RandString(50)
End Sub
```

Typical output looks like:

```
fvdDUV1csFLhzCmrvJtYx4wXr1QGqSai6yiGSC4ByzB53kG5E1
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending @John Coleman's answer.

Here the "Anonymise" function will create a random string or number based on your input. If you pass a string, it will return a string, if you pass a number, it will return a number. Note that the length of the return value will be the same as your input value

```html
Public Function Anonymise(str As String)
chunks = Split(str, " ")
Dim ret As String
ret = ""

If IsNumeric(str) = False Then
    For i = 0 To UBound(chunks) - LBound(chunks)
        ret = ret + " " + RandString(Len(chunks(i)))
    Next i
    ret = Trim(ret)
    Anonymise = StrConv(ret, vbProperCase)
Else
    For i = 0 To UBound(chunks) - LBound(chunks)
        ret = ret + " " + RandNum(Len(chunks(i)))
    Next i
    ret = Trim(ret)
    Anonymise = ret
End If
End Function

Function RandString(n As Long) As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, m As Long, s As String, pool As String
    pool = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    m = Len(pool)
    For i = 1 To n
        j = 1 + Int(m * Rnd())
        s = s & Mid(pool, j, 1)
    Next i
    RandString = s
End Function


Function RandNum(n As Long) As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, m As Long, s As String, pool As String
    pool = "0123456789"
    m = Len(pool)
    For i = 1 To n
        j = 1 + Int(m * Rnd())
        s = s & Mid(pool, j, 1)
    Next i
    RandNum = s
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

For those wanting speed, you would want to avoid string concatenation with `&`.  Concatenation can be done much faster with an array of characters and Join(), as documented in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400791/creating-a-string-from-an-array-of-strings-fastest-method) question.

The function below skips Join() and uses byte arrays for an additional speed boost (for more on that, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51244433/11653404) answer).

```
Function RandStringFromPool(stringLength As Long, charPool As String) As String

    Randomize
    Dim returnByteArray() As Byte
    Dim poolByteArray() As Byte: poolByteArray = StrConv(charPool, vbFromUnicode)
    Dim poolSize As Long: poolSize = Len(charPool)
    
    ReDim returnByteArray(0 To stringLength * 2 - 1)
    For i = 0 To UBound(returnByteArray) Step 2
        returnByteArray(i) = poolByteArray(Int(Rnd() * poolSize))
    Next
    RandStringFromPool = returnByteArray
    
End Function
```