# Processing hundreds of thousands of SQL Server rows in VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, dao, adodb

I have a few SQL server tables, one with 200,000 rows and the other 900,000 rows, both with maybe 50 columns. I need to download them to a csv file, and within VBA script (it's inside Excel). All rows and all columns are required to be exported.

Presume you have a recordset oRec taken from a simple query. All columns are varchars, most are either varchar(20) or varchar(200)

```
'SELECT * FROM TABLE'.
```

In the below code I loop through the recordset and then through each column. If I comment out column looping or just get the first column it's pretty fast. But every column is exponentially making it worse to taking over an hour.

Is there a better way? I need every row and column and VBA/Excel is the only way as it's part of a system within Excel to process data. This is for end users and so they don't have sql tools, libraries (just office) and I cannot distribute applications. This export is just one tiny part of a larger Excel automation project.

```
While Not oRec.EOF
    sLine = ""
    LineCount = LineCount + 1
        For Each col In oRec.Fields

            If IsNull(col.value) Then
                sVal = "NULL"
            Else
                sVal = col.value
            End If

            If Not bHaveHeader Then
                sHeader = sHeader & CStr(col.name) & ","
                sLine = sLine & "," & sVal
            Else
                sLine = sLine & "," & sVal
            End If
            colOffset = colOffset + 1
        Next
        colOffset = 0
        If bHaveHeader Then
            sLines = sLines & Right(sLine, Len(sLine) - 1) & vbCrLf
        Else
            If LineCount Mod EXPORT_LINE_BUFFER = 0 Then
                'lines ready to be exported. last line can't have carriage return
                sLines = sHeader & vbCrLf & sLines & Right(sLine, Len(sLine) - 1)
                Call UpdateFile(fs, sExportFile, sLines)
                sLines = ""
            Else
                sLines = sHeader & vbCrLf & sLines & Right(sLine, Len(sLine) - 1) & vbCrLf
            End If
        End If

        bHaveHeader = True

    oRec.MoveNext
Wend
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this with VBA? If you do need to use a CSV, I would suggest there are better options

Comment: Please define columns as they may carry high overhead such as `blob` , high precision numbers, and max `varchar`. Please also show example of *when I put in a fairly small set (e.g. 3000 rows)*.

Comment: What happens in VBA after you open the recordset?  Are you saying it takes 30min to get past that `Execute` line?

Comment: @Neil, is that 64-bit or 32-bit Excel? And please add the code that copies the recordset data into the Excel sheet.

Comment: Right, sorry, my fault, I made a right botch of the question. didn't profile it correctly. It's not the query at fault, it's the column looping. I'll update the question.

Comment: If you're building up a CSV string to write to a file, then skip the concatenation and write directly to the file as you loop.

Comment: But still, why VBA? Wouldn't `bcp` or a proper ETL tool just be better?

Comment: @larnu this is enterprise land and it's given to normal users. Not allowed to create or distribute applications and they don't have tools like bcp.

Comment: But *normal* users are allowed to extract the **entire** table? I admit the users at the office don't have access to `bcp`, but also they don't have access to extract the entire tables at a whim. If they did, we'd supply some form of application layer to do that; where they wouldn't be able to edit the code (because they would be able to with a VBA Macro).

Comment: Maybe try looking at `https://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_rs_getstring.asp`  Not sure how well it performs with huge recordsets though.

Comment: @larnu this data they receive is a forecast that they run on data they already own

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks, I'll give it a try. My current trial is extracting all the columns names and concatenating them as a single string, i.e. return one column per row. I suspect it'll be costly as I have to cast and convert nulls...

Comment: `GetString` will handle nulls for you - just pass it what you want them to be represented as.  Any performance changes though will likely be mostly dependent on what your current value for EXPORT_LINE_BUFFER is, and how wide your table is (ie. how much concatenation are you actually doing).  You could also look into using a StringBuilder class instead of using concatenation: that will also be faster.  Example here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070863/hidden-features-of-vba

Comment: It works, about 10 minutes and I worry of memory. However, if I use the 'get data' option inside Excel to connect to my database and load data, it takes <1 minute to retrieve all the data into a sheet, so there must be a better way than my code. I guess I could automate the get data option if all else fails...