# Native DLL for uploading data

Tags: windows, dll, native, uploading

I need a Windows DLL that allows posting data to specific webpage. A good example is [ISX](http://www.dateiliste.com/d3files/tools/mphider/isxdl.htm), which is excellent in downloading, but unfortunately doesn't support POST request.

This will be used to build a portable application in VB6. Because winsock.ocx is not always available and requires registration, I'm looking for a registration-free native alternative.

Are there any similar DLLs available?

Need something simple and straightforward, like `PostData (url, data)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always build [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) or [neon](http://www.webdav.org/neon/) as a DLL: you'll need to do the VB6 declarations, but there's no reason why you wouldnt be able to work them in you can't package winsock.ocx into your installer.

EDIT: see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/vb/. Not sure how current/recent it is, but it would probably be a decent start.

Comment: This looks rather complex and C++ project doesn't compile in VS2010. Any other suggestions? I only need one function to upload string via http.

Answer (score 1):

There is a ubiquitous COM object called "MSXML2.XMLHTTP" that can do GET and POST requests and return you the results. You would just have to write a wrapper function to simplify it down to (url,data)

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308826/msxml2-xmlhttp-send-method-works-with-early-binding-fails-with-late-binding)

As a side note, if you find that lots of client-level proxy/lan/security settings are messing up your connection you can try the alternate "MSXML2.**Server**XMLHTTP" which will connect in a more raw fashion.