# Reading HTML file in VBA Excel

Tags: vba

i want to read the HTML code in VBA (something like URL in Java).  I need to save it in a string.  I parse it afterwards.

alpan67

Comment: Do you mean `URL decoding into a String`? e.g. `java.net.URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8")`;

Comment: I need to read the HTML code, it is a football table and i decode it later.  How can i save the HTML of the website ? In Java i can create a URL and then openconnection etc. etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a function for you. It will return the String of the HTML returned by a given URL.

```
Function GetHTML(URL As String) As String
    Dim HTML As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .Send
        GetHTML = .ResponseText
    End With
End Function
```

Just make sure your provided URL is well formed. I.E. it includes the `http://` or `https://` if appropriate.

For Example: `GetHtml("www.google.com")` is incorrect. 
You would want `GetHtml("https://www.google.com/")`

Comment: Thanks - how do you avoid the response text being truncated?

Comment: I used your code and I get "Access denied" error at `.Send`. Any idea why? 
(Note: I used very common URLs (http://www.google.com, http://www.youtube.com, etc. that normally have no problem to be opened programmatically.)

Comment: Thanks. I found a solution using CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

Answer (score 0):

- To do the [URL DECODING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998715/does-vba-have-any-built-in-url-decoding) you may use that post as a reference.
- Here goes a [article that uses MS Word to save html of web page as text](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/109109-Save-HTML-as-Text-in-VBA-%28VBA-Access-2007%29).
- Code in Excel VBA - [from VBAExpress](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?t=27050): I wouldn't fancy copying his code. You may give it a try and comment.