# VBA getting data seen in Javascript tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel, vba

I am trying to extract the data that a javascript tooltip displays, but have no idea how to do it. I thought maybe an XMLHTTP request needs to be sent to the server, but honestly I am not sure. Below is the JS tooltip code to show and hide the tool tip. Is there something else I have to look for other than this to help me get the information that the tooltip shows and put that data in an excel sheet? I really would like some help from beginning to end on this, because I honestly do not know how to start it. Thank you very much.

```
< a href="javascript:gotopage('D35555')" on mouse over="ajax_showTooltip('D35555','DATA_PAGE',this);return false" on mouse out="ajax_hideTooltip()" >
```

Here is a link below to Mr. Excel, that I posted the question on, but I do no think they understand what I am trying to do. Thank you

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/827332-parsing-javascript-%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A-text.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like that to read parent file

```
Function GetHTML(URL As String) As String
    Dim HTML As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .Send
        GetHTML = .ResponseText
    End With
End Function
```

From [Reading HTML file in VBA Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103220/reading-html-file-in-vba-excel)

Then find anchor tags as shown in code below

```
Private Sub SomeMethod()

   Dim URL As String, Result As String
    URL = "http://localhost/ajax-tooltip/ajax-tooltip.html"

   Result = GetHTML(URL)

    Dim Document As Object
    Set Document = New HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLElement As IHTMLElement

    Document.Open
    Document.write Result
    Document.Close

    Dim ElementCollection As IHTMLElementCollection
    Set ElementCollection = Document.getElementsByTagName("a")

Dim mouseOverValue As String

For Each HTMLElement In ElementCollection


    If Not IsNull(HTMLElement.getAttribute("onmouseover")) Then
        mouseOverValue = HTMLElement.getAttribute("onmouseover")
        If InStr(mouseOverValue, "ajax_showTooltip") Then
            MsgBox ("Find your page here and read its HTML: " + mouseOverValue)
        End If
    End If

Next HTMLElement

End Sub
```

Parse mouseOverValue to get value of tooltip page and call `GetHTML` again for tooltip page

Comment: I do not think that I was specific enough as to where the data can be found. What do I need to do if the data is being pulled from an internal SQL database? Thank you.