# Does Windows have any built-in utility to encode/decode URL?

Tags: windows, urlencode, url-encoding, urldecode

The certutil utiliiy in Windows can be used to perform Base64 encoding and deocding. Is there any built-in utility for URL encoding and decoding? There are many free tools available on web. But I am specifically looking for Windows built-in utility or if not simple script that can run on Windows.

Thanks!

Comment: Encoding/decoding between a URL and Base64 or do you mean things like `InternetCanonicalizeUrl` and `UrlEscape`

Comment: I meant encoding certain characters in a URL by replacing them with one or more character triplets that consist of the percent character "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gbm64/ for base64 encode/decode; http://sourceforge.net/projects/urlexam/ for url encode/decode

Comment: @zedfoxus, I cannot "download" any external tool in my office.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Base64 VBA**

Base64 encoding and decoding can be done with VBA. You can copy/paste [this code](http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/vbasic/Base64Coder.bas.txt) and put it in Excel VBA, for example, and then use it's methods to encode and decode Base64.

**URL encode/decode VBA**

[How can I URL encode a string in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218181/how-can-i-url-encode-a-string-in-excel-vba) and [Does VBA have any built in URL decoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998715/does-vba-have-any-built-in-url-decoding) is a URL decoder. Using these tools you should be able to encode and decode within Windows environment with MS Office products such as Excel and VBA.

**Base64 PowerShell**

If you use powershell, check this out: http://vstepic.blogspot.com/2013/02/how-to-convert-string-to-base64-and.html. Excerpt from that site:

```
PS C:\Temp>$b  = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World")
PS C:\Temp>[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($b)
SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=

PS C:\Temp>$b  = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String("SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=")
PS C:\Temp>[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($b)
Hello World
```

**URL encode/decode PowerShell**

For URL encode/decode you could use:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web") | Out-Null
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("http://test.com/?path=what is")
http%3a%2f%2ftest.com%2f%3fpath%3dwhat+is

[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode("http%3a%2f%2ftest.com%2f%3fpath%3dwhat+is")
http://test.com/?path=what is
```

Reference: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Encoding-and-Decoding-URL-99dc4256

Comment: Does poweshell solution needs .net framework installed on machine?

Comment: Yes (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847769.aspx). Powershell requires .NET framework

Comment: Thanks! I will go ahead with Powershell script solution.

Answer (score 1):

For me `[System.Net.WebUtility]` worked instead of `[System.Web.HttpUtility]`