# Sending data from excel to Server using HTTP Post

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, vba, http-post

How can I send data to Server from excel using HTTP Post?

Lets say the URL is: http://testingHttpPost/

And I want to send data from Cells A2 and B2. How would I get this done in VBA?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Sub XMLPost()
Dim xmlhttp, sData As String

    With ActiveSheet
        sData = "x=" & URLencode(.Range("A2").Value) & _
                "&y=" & URLencode(.Range("B2").Value)
    End With

    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("microsoft.xmlhttp")

    With xmlhttp
        .Open "POST", " http://testingHttpPost/", False
        .setrequestheader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send sData
        Debug.Print .responsetext
    End With
End Sub
```

For URLencode function see here: [How can I URL encode a string in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218181/how-can-i-url-encode-a-string-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Thanks! Tim

In your above example, If I want to insert the data in a SQL Server DB. Using your above example of HTTP Post how could I insert the "x" and "y" data in Table "DataTable" in columns "X" and "Y" respectively?

Comment: Sorry - I'm not that familiar with asp.net(mvc).  Typically the values X and Y will show up in the request.form name-value collection.  Once you have those you can use ADO to do the insert.  That's about as much as I can offer.  I suggest you post a more specific question on that, including what language you're using for your asp.net