# Creating 2D (Data Matrix or QR Codes) in MS Access Reports/Forms

Tags: ms-access, qr-code

We are in the process of implementing code to read/create 2D bar codes that are starting to show up on our supplier's parts.

We have a need to create the 2D bar codes in MS Access reports and forms.  Has anyone had success with the font (IDAutomation) or Active X (dlSoft) solutions out there.

For C#, the open source library "http://barcoderender.codeplex.com/" was suggested.  Any thoughts on how successful this was or if anyone has other open-source and/or pay for options.

Thanks,

Anton

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the volume of codes you need to generate, you could use the Google Charts API to generate QR Codes.

Simply add a "Microsoft Web Browser" ActiveX component and the following code to your Form:

```
Dim Size As Integer
Dim Text As String
Dim URL As String
Size = 200
Text = "This is my test"
' Better to actually use a URL encoding function like those described here:
' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218181/how-can-i-url-encode-a-string-in-excel-vba
Text = Replace(Text, " ", "%20")
URL = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=" & Size & "x" & Size & "&cht=qr&chld=H|0&chl=" & Text
WebBrowser.Navigate (URL)
```

You can of course change the Size and the Text depending on your need. The Text can also be a value directly from your Form, therefore your data.

I would advise you to check Googles Terms and Services before using it.

Answer (score 0):

I completely escaped the web browser control and the Google API since that functionality is now deprecated from what I can tell. I went with a different free API but the Google API or any other API could be used instead.

In my example I am creating an .png image in the same directory as the application. I have a text box on my form named txtToCode in which I type in any text I want to code. I also have an image control so that the image can be viewed from the form, but you can modify it how you wish:

```
Private Sub btnCode2_Click()
     Call GetQRCode(Me.txtToCode, 150, 150)
End Sub

Sub GetQRCode(Content As String, Width As Integer, Height As Integer)
    Dim ByteData() As Byte
    Dim XmlHttp As Object
    Dim HttpReq As String
    Dim ReturnContent As String
    Dim EncContent As String
    Dim QRImage As String
    EncContent = EncodeURL(Content)

    HttpReq = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=" & EncContent & "&size=" & Width & "x" & Height & ""

    Set XmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XmlHttp")
    XmlHttp.Open "GET", HttpReq, False
    XmlHttp.Send
    ByteData = XmlHttp.responseBody
    Set XmlHttp = Nothing

    ReturnContent = StrConv(ByteData, vbUnicode)
    Call ExportImage(ReturnContent)
End Sub

Private Sub ExportImage(image As String)
    Dim FilePath As String

    On Error GoTo NoSave

    ' Build Export Path
    FilePath = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\qr.png"


    Open FilePath For Binary As #1
       Put #1, 1, image
    Close #1
    Me.Image3.Picture = FilePath
    ' Save File Path
    Exit Sub
NoSave:
MsgBox "Could not save the QR Code Image! Reason: " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "File Save Error"
End Sub

Private Function EncodeURL(str As String)
    Dim ScriptEngine As Object
    Dim encoded As String
    Dim Temp As String

    Temp = Replace(str, " ", "%20")
    Temp = Replace(Temp, "#", "%23")
    EncodeURL = Temp
End Function
```

Comment: Hi can you help to generate multi line `QR Code`. Means One line then new line under first line.

Comment: @Harun24HR We have done something similar by using a report with an image control used in printing labels. I built a function based on the above code and used it within the recordsource of the report to generate the QR Code for each line item.

Comment: Hi @AnthonyGriggs, is it possible to just generate pictures on report instead of saving each one of them ?

Comment: @AlbertSan None that I am aware of. Maybe instead of a file location converting it into a Base64 string? You could maybe experiment with that if your really not into the file location... but I am unsure if that will work in this scenario as I am not aware of an image control in Access that accepts Base64 strings... they might exist... but I have never tried.