# XmlHttp Post in Excel VBA not updating website form

Tags: vba, excel, xmlhttprequest, excel-2010, msxml

I routinely have to search the state of NV for unclaimed property and put the results in an Excel spreadsheet. I am trying to automate the process but I'm limited to using Excel 2010 and VBA. Below is the URL to the site I'm trying to submit a form using xmlhttp.

URL: https://nevadatreasurer.gov/UPSearch/

I created a class to automate submitting forms on other websites but no matter what I enter in the postdata the form is never submitted. Below is my submission, and method to submit the form.

Call to class:

```
cXML.openWebsite "Post", "https://nevadatreasurer.gov/UPSearch/Index.aspx", _
                 "ctl04$txtOwner=" & strSearchName
```

Class method:

```
Public Sub openWebsite(strOpenMethod As String, strURL As String, _
Optional strPostData As String)

pXmlHttp.Open strOpenMethod, strURL


If strPostData <> "" Then
    strPostData = convertSpaceToPlus(strPostData)
    pXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    pXmlHttp.send (strPostData)
Else
    pXmlHttp.send
End If

'Create DOM html documnet
pHtmlObj.body.innerHTML = pXmlHttp.responseText

End Sub
```

Each time the `responseText` is the main website with no updates, as if I submitted no postdata. I'm fairly new to IE automation but can someone provide a reason why this isn't working and a code example that works?

Thanks!

Update: 7/26/13 8:30am PST

Without any changes to my method I was able to submit forms through another website. The state of OR unclaimed property form. It worked perfect!

URL: https://oregonup.us/upweb/up/UP_search.asp

However I ran into the same problem when I tried the state of CA unclaimed property website. No matter what I do, the `responseText` is always the original search page with no update.

URL: https://scoweb.sco.ca.gov/UCP/Default.aspx

It still does not work with the state of NV on my original post. I am using the proper post data, URL encoded for each website and can see no difference. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Try below code

```
Public Sub openWebsite(strOpenMethod As String, strURL As String, Optional strPostData As String)

    Dim pXmlHttp As Object
    Set pXmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    pXmlHttp.Open strOpenMethod, strURL, False
    pXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    pXmlHttp.send (strPostData)


    Dim pHtmlObj As Object
    Set pHtmlObj = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    pHtmlObj.body.innerHTML = pXmlHttp.ResponseText
    MsgBox pXmlHttp.ResponseText

End Sub

Sub test()
    Dim btnSearch As String, strSearchType As String, strSearchName As String, PostData As String
    btnSearch = "Search"
    strSearchType = "Owner"
    strSearchName = "Santosh"
    PostData = "ctl04%24txtOwner=" & strSearchName & "&ctl04%24btnSearch=" & btnSearch & "&ctl04%24rblSearchType=" & strSearchType
    openWebsite "POST", "https://nevadatreasurer.gov/UPSearch/Index.aspx", PostData
End Sub
```

**Post Data view using Firebug**

[image]

**URL encode**

[image]

**ResponeText**

[image]

Comment: @Andy I urlencoded my postdata manually, & using your code with no change to the results. The responceText is always the orginal search page with no change. You can't see the entire responce in the MsgBox but if you save the text you get this code: `<table width="100%"> <tr> <td width="33%" valign="top"> </td> <td width="33%" valign="top">` If you view the source on the webpage you get: `<table width="100%"><tr><td width="33%" valign="top"><div id="ctl04_pnlResults" style="background-color:#66CCFF;border-color:Blue;border-width:2px;border-style:Solid;">` Followed by the results

Comment: Excuse me, Santosh, would you mind taking a look at my question? It is similar to this one and I've based my code on this answer. However I'm still having trouble with it and no one seems to be looking at my question... Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38570380/ Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should urlencode the characters in this string:

```
"ctl04$txtOwner=" & strSearchName
```

Ways to do this are discussed here: [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218181/how-can-i-url-encode-a-string-in-excel-vba), as VBA doesn't have a built-in function for this.

The dollar sign needs to be replaced with %24 and any spaces with %20. If these are the only non-alphanumeric characters in the string they you could take a simple approach, using `VBA.Replace()` (twice). You are currently replacing spaces with '+' which will usually work, but the dollar-sign may be an issue.