# VBA HTTP POST Parameter Incorrect

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA so this is probably my problem.  I am trying to perform a HTTP POST from Excel to a web service, and I can POST quite happily, until I change the code so that I am posting content in my message, at which point I get the following error:

> Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)':
>
> The Parameter is incorrect.

My code is as follows:

```
Dim oHttp As Object
Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
Call oHttp.Open("POST", url, False)
oHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/text"
oHttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
Call oHttp.send(content)
httpPOST = oHttp.responseText
```

The line which is killing the code is the oHttp.send - if I do not pass any content then it is fine, as soon as I put content here it is unhappy.

The content parameter is a large string containing comma separated text and includes line feeds.  I think this is why it is unhappy, if I change the string to simply a short "Hello" then the send is sucessful and the application happily makes it to the next line, before hitting the run-time error:

> The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available

So I guess my question is, how do I POST a large block of text to a server?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need `Call` or the the brackets wrapping the parameters for either of the two code lines they are used in. *content* is blank; while you may have removed the string assignment, you should have redacted it so we can see a version of what you are trying to pass into the post operation.

Comment: Maybe try encoding your data?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818903/xmlhttp-post-in-excel-vba-not-updaing-website-form  Also make sure your url is correctly formatted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, I managed to get it to work by converting the string to a binary array and then send the binary array over.