# VBA code - connect to webpage and retrieve value

Tags: excel, vba, web, web-scraping

I have the following

- Column A == FEdEX AWB #s
- Column B == Delivery date (Empty)

I would like to write a function where it reads the tracking number on Column A and extracts the delivery date from the website - all AWB # are delivered - 100% sure

The code I have writes all the info found in the website into the sheet - not sure how to extract only the delivered date.

```
Sub Macro1()
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;https://www.bing.com/packagetrackingv2? 
    packNum=727517426234&carrier=Fedex&FORM=PCKTR1" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = _
    "https://www.bing.com/packagetrackingv2? 
     packNum=727517426234&carrier=Fedex&FORM=PCKTR1"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
   .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
   .SavePassword = False
   .SaveData = True
   .AdjustColumnWidth = True
   .RefreshPeriod = 0
   .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
   .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
   .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
   .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
   .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
   .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
   .WebDisableRedirections = False
   .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: can u post a printscreen how the data is ?

Answer (score 1):

A function, getting passing the airway bill number and returning the date would be quite enough:

```
Function GetDateFromAwb(awbNumber As String) As String

    Dim objIE As New InternetExplorer   'Microsoft Internet Controls library added
    objIE.Visible = False               'Or put True, if you want to see the IE

    objIE.navigate "https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?tracknumbers=" & awbNumber

    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

    GetDateFromAwb = objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("redesignSnapshotTVC snapshotController_date dest").Item.InnerText
    objIE.Quit

End Function
```

The idea of the function is to append the airbill string number to the URL and to open the corresponding site. Then, using the class "redesignSnapshotTVC snapshotController_date dest", the corresponding date is taken.

This is a possible way to call the function, displaying the date in a MsgBox:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim awbNumber As String
    awbNumber = 727517426234#
    Dim awbDate As String

    awbDate = GetDateFromAwb(awbNumber)
    MsgBox awbDate

End Sub
```

Make sure that the library "Microsoft Internet Controls" is added from the VBE menu>Extras>References:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a browser you could use xmlhttp request which is quicker.

The page does a form [XHR](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/) POST request which returns json you can parse (lots of info returned including a delivery date field). You can use this as a function in the sheet. I also show a test call. The id (tracking number) is passed as an argument to the function `GetDeliveryDate`.

Here is the request made when you submit your tracking number on the site:

[image]

As you can see from the above, and further detailed in code, the tracking number is part of the body sent in the request (data param); it is also part of one of the request headers.

I use [jsonconverter.bas](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) to parse the json response. After adding the code from there to your project you need go VBE > Tools > References and add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

View the json response [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=ba200b2876334f22abeea615bf82115c)

As you say all requests will return a delivery date, if you don't want to load this external library you could use `split` to isolate the date.

---

**Relevant json:**

You can see relevant part of json here:

[image]

I use the field `actDeliveryDt` for version of code using split as I can separate an unambiguous date yyyy-mm-dd from the datetime string. I use `displayActDeliveryDt` for json parsing though you could use either (removing time part with split if usnig the former as shown in examples below)

Caveat: I have had only one delivery id to use for testing.

---

**TODO:**

1. You could add in a test for whether a valid request was made as the json response includes a field for this.
2. If performing this for multiple requests I would recommend, for efficiency, to re-write using a sub which loops an array of the tracking numbers, stores results in an array and writes that array out in go at end.

---

**VBA:**

JSON parsing:

```
Option Explicit 'example test call from VBE
Public Sub test()    
    Debug.Print GetDeliveryDate(727517426234#)
End Sub

 Public Function GetDeliveryDate(ByVal id As Double) As Date
    Dim json As Object, body As String  '<  VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    body = "data={""TrackPackagesRequest"":{""appType"":""WTRK"",""appDeviceType"":""DESKTOP"",""supportHTML"":true,""supportCurrentLocation"":true,""uniqueKey"":"""",""processingParameters"":{},""trackingInfoList"":[{""trackNumberInfo"":{""trackingNumber"":" & Chr$(34) & CStr(id) & Chr$(34) & ",""trackingQualifier"":"""",""trackingCarrier"":""""}}]}}"
    body = body & "&action=trackpackages&locale=en_US&version=1&format=json"

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", "https://www.fedex.com/trackingCal/track", False
        .setRequestHeader "Referer", "https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?tracknumbers=" & CStr(id)
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .setRequestHeader "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        .send body
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
    End With
    GetDeliveryDate = json("TrackPackagesResponse")("packageList")(1)("displayActDeliveryDt")
End Function
```

Using split:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
   Debug.Print GetDeliveryDate(727517426234#)
End Sub


Public Function GetDeliveryDate(ByVal id As Double) As Date
    Dim s As String, body As String
    body = "data={""TrackPackagesRequest"":{""appType"":""WTRK"",""appDeviceType"":""DESKTOP"",""supportHTML"":true,""supportCurrentLocation"":true,""uniqueKey"":"""",""processingParameters"":{},""trackingInfoList"":[{""trackNumberInfo"":{""trackingNumber"":" & Chr$(34) & CStr(id) & Chr$(34) & ",""trackingQualifier"":"""",""trackingCarrier"":""""}}]}}"
    body = body & "&action=trackpackages&locale=en_US&version=1&format=json"

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", "https://www.fedex.com/trackingCal/track", False
        .setRequestHeader "Referer", "https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?tracknumbers=" & CStr(id)
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .setRequestHeader "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        .send body
        s = .responseText
    End With
    GetDeliveryDate = Split(Replace$(Split(Split(s, """actDeliveryDt"":""")(1), Chr$(34))(0), "\u002d", "-"), "T")(0)
End Function
```

---

**Example usage in sheet:**

Note: I have UK format dd/mm/yyyy in sheet

[image]

Comment: I would liek to use this but it is not working - where do i copy paste this Json code found on the link provided ? do i copy everything ? i did copy it on mymodule in VBA and it gives me errors ??? i have never used this Json before, any step by step instruction would be appreciated - Thanks

Comment: go to https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas  > click raw > copy all the code > in your vba project right click insert standard module > press F4 rename as JSONConverter, paste the code inside that module. Then VBE > Tools > References > Add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

Comment: i did what you suggested - copy the code - and add the function 'using JASON Parsin' in to the VBA under the ThisWorkbook page in VBA. It gave me the following error - under the JSON converter code - it did not recognize the first line "Attribute VB_Name = "JsonConverter"" - giving me a Compile error Syntax error so i cancel out that line and when i run it again (the public sub test()) it gave me this error "Run-Time Error '5' invalid procedure call or argument.............

Comment: Then i moved the code - function into the same module wherei put the JSON Converter - when i run the test function it gives me a runtime error "The parameter is incorrect" when i hit on debug it highlights the line " .send body"  under the GetDeliveryDate function - within the Create Object("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

Comment: Sorry, i left home yesterday, i just saw your comment and the link does not longer contain the file-  i will be in front of my computer for th enext 8 hrs....

Comment: One moment then,

Comment: Got the file, and still does not work, when i open VBA and run teh Public Sub Test function from VBA it gives me this error " Run time error '-2147024809(80070057) The parameter is incorrect" - i am running Windows 7 Enterprise service pack 1 64 bit - Microsoft Excel 2013

Comment: and when i hit debug on the error - VBA highlits the line ".send body" within the getDeliveryDate function

Comment: also , i see in your code that you are colling Mozilla/5.0 - i do not have mozilla installed only chrome and IE, could this be the reason ?

Comment: i also found this post (it seems to have exactly the same issue as i am having)- however i do not fully understand the solution --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565971/vba-http-post-parameter-incorrect

Comment: Not sure but shouldn’t be user agent as that could be pretty much any value. I’ll have to have a look later

Comment: You can always pull your user-agent from dev tools network tab or using online what’s my user agent tool.