# Excel parses Hebrew chars to Google as gibberish

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using VB to parse values form Excel spreadsheet to Google search.

```
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="http://www.google.com./search?hl=en&q=" + Sheet1.name1, NewWindow:=True
```

When I try to parse Hebrew chars I get gibberish. Can't find the reason for this...

Comment: Do you have the same language packs installed on both your default internet browser and excel?  Obviously, You have them in excel or you wouldn't be getting surprised by seeing gibberish

Comment: Where are the Hebrew chars? In the `Sheet1.name1`?

Answer (score 2):

It's an encoding issue, you can either change encoding, which is kind of complicated, because excel defaults to your system encoding.

I think the easiest thing to do in your case is to [URL Encode](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) your query.

Prior to Excel 2013, use this can be done with this snippet, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218181/how-can-i-url-encode-a-string-in-excel-vba)

```
Public Function URLEncode( _
   StringVal As String, _
   Optional SpaceAsPlus As Boolean = False _
) As String

  Dim StringLen As Long: StringLen = Len(StringVal)

  If StringLen > 0 Then
    ReDim result(StringLen) As String
    Dim i As Long, CharCode As Integer
    Dim Char As String, Space As String

    If SpaceAsPlus Then Space = "+" Else Space = "%20"

    For i = 1 To StringLen
      Char = Mid$(StringVal, i, 1)
      CharCode = Asc(Char)
      Select Case CharCode
        Case 97 To 122, 65 To 90, 48 To 57, 45, 46, 95, 126
          result(i) = Char
        Case 32
          result(i) = Space
        Case 0 To 15
          result(i) = "%0" & Hex(CharCode)
        Case Else
          result(i) = "%" & Hex(CharCode)
      End Select
    Next i
    URLEncode = Join(result, "")
  End If
End Function
```

In Excel 2013, you can use the `EncodeUrl` function as such

```
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="http://www.google.com./search?hl=en&q=" + WorksheetFunction.EncodeUrl(Sheet1.name1), NewWindow:=True
```

Comment: Thank you so for that. I've sent this solution to my developer and hopefully he can solve this once and for all :

Comment: You're welcome, please accept the answer or at least vote-up if it was helpful