# Handle Special Characters in VBA on ms Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, httprequest

I'm writing a VBA code to check for access for my Database:
The code check if I have privilege to connect to a web server so it grants me access to the DB.

```
Function WebVer(ByVal StrUserName As String, ByVal StrPassword As String) As String

   Dim Access As String
   Dim objHTTP As Object
   Dim URL As String
   Dim Response As String


   Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
   URL = "http://myweb.com/authenticator?app=WebDNC_server&service=authenticate&userid=" & StrUserName & "&password=" & StrPassword    
   objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
   objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
   objHTTP.Send ("")
   LDAPResponse = UCase(objHTTP.responseText)

    If Response Like "*BAD*" Then
        WebVer= "BAD PASSWORD"
    ElseIf Response Like "*PASS*" Then
        WebVer= "PASS"
    ElseIf Response Like "*USERID*" Then
        WebVer= "USERID Not RECOGNIZED"
    Else
        WebVer= "CONNECTION ERROR"
    End If



End Function
```

Now everything is going fine except that if the user uses special characters in the password it returns BAD Password. I think there is a problem on how VBA handles Special characters but still do not know how to solve it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you have to URL-encode the username and password.

See: [How can I URL encode a string in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218181/how-can-i-url-encode-a-string-in-excel-vba)