# VBA Word : Error 5174 when Documents.Open with filename including pound sign #

Tags: vba, ms-word

In Microsoft Word 2010 VBA

I am getting a runtime error 5174, when trying to open a document which file name includes a pound sign "#", with a relative file path.

```
Sub openPoundedFilename()
    Dim doc As Object
    ' Both files "C:\Temp\foo_bar.docx" and "C:\Temp\foo#bar.docx" exist

    ' With absolute file paths
    Set doc = Documents.Open(fileName:="C:\Temp\foo_bar.docx") ' Works
    doc.Close
    Set doc = Documents.Open(fileName:="C:\Temp\foo#bar.docx") ' Works
    doc.Close

    ' With relative file paths
    ChDir "C:\Temp"
    Set doc = Documents.Open(fileName:="foo_bar.docx") ' Works
    doc.Close
    Set doc = Documents.Open(fileName:="foo#bar.docx") ' Does not work !!!!
    'Gives runtime error 5174 file not found (C:\Temp\foo)
    doc.Close
End Sub
```

I did not find any explanation for why the last `Documents.Open` fails.

It probably has to do with some mismatch regarding the "#" sign used for URL.

(see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/202261)

Thanks in advance for answers

---

*Edit 17/10/2016 13:37:17*

The macro recording generates the following:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\Temp\"
    Documents.Open fileName:="foo#bar.docx", ConfirmConversions:=False, _
        ReadOnly:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False, PasswordDocument:="", _
        PasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, WritePasswordDocument:="", _
        WritePasswordTemplate:="", Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, XMLTransform:=""
End Sub
```

This macro doesn't work (gives the same error 5174).

Comment: Anything after # is considered as sub-address, so you can try Record Macro to see the generated code.

Comment: seems to work only with the full path `Documents.Open CurDir & "\foo#bar.docx"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open the file using a relative path you need to URLEncode the filename. There is no built-in support in VBA for doing so (besides in [newer Excel versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24301379/40347)), but you can use @Tomalak's **[`URLEncode`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/218199/40347)** function, which should encode `foo#bar.docx` as `foo%23bar.docx`:

```
ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\Temp\"

Dim urlEncodedFilename as String
urlEncodedFilename = URLEncode("foo#bar.docx")
Set doc = Documents.Open(fileName:=urlEncodedFilename)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the issue only occurred with relative path names, a work-around could be used:
convert paths to absolute.

```
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set doc = Documents.Open(fileName:=fs.GetAbsolutePathName("foo#bar.docx"))
```

Maybe this work-around doesn't work in all cases, as `Documents.Open` performs unclear processing with the file name.