# VBA for Excel, how to load a .js file as Jscript Scriptcontrol object

Tags: javascript, vba, excel

I know it's a bit silly to load a js into VBA, but I need to load the libphonenumber library by Google to perform an analysis of a big bunch of phone numbers.

I tried to adapt the following code borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14495932/8112768), but the compiled library is to big to be inserted into the Vba code.

Is there any way to load the .js library from a file instead? 
Thanks!

```
Function encodeURL(str As String)
   Dim ScriptEngine As ScriptControl
   Set ScriptEngine = New ScriptControl

   ScriptEngine.Language = "JScript"
   ScriptEngine.AddCode "function encode(str) {return encodeURIComponent(str);}"
   Dim encoded As String

   encoded = ScriptEngine.Run("encode", str)
   encodeURL = encoded
End Function
```

### UPDATE.

This should be a working code, but for some reason doesn't works:

```
Function loabdjs(x As String)

    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    Dim script As String
    Dim fs As Scripting.TextStream

    ''' CODE : "function encode(str) {return encodeURIComponent(str);}"
    Set fs = fso.OpenTextFile("test.js", ForReading, False)
    MsgBox ("Never reached this point")


    script = fs.ReadAll

    fs.Close

    Dim ScriptEngine As ScriptControl
    Set ScriptEngine = New ScriptControl

    Dim output As String

    ScriptEngine.Language = "JScript"
    ScriptEngine.AddCode script

    output = ScriptEngine.Run("encode", x)
    loadjs = output
End Function
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "the compiled library is to big to be inserted into the Vba code"?

Comment: I tried to simply paste it in the addCode method, but it is about 220kb of code, too long for a line, too big to be inserted including underscores.

Comment: Try adding a try catch block to the js function with empty catch.

Comment: Run the code in the VBA debugger and ensure you have error-handling set-up correctly (i.e. don't use `On Error Resume Next`). It sounds like `OpenTextFile` is failing. There will be an error message displayed somewhere, go find it.

Answer (score 2):

Read the library from the filesystem into a string:

```
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

Dim fs As Scripting.TextStream
Set fs = fso.OpenTextFile( "libphonenumber.js", ForReading, False )

Dim script As String
script = fs.ReadAll

fs.Close()

scriptEngine.AddCode script
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I didn't succeed with this code. Tried a little Helloworld test, and still not working. Am I missing something? (see update on post)

Answer (score 0):

may be this:

Function loa**bd**js(x As String)

...

...

loa**d**js = output

End Function

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but for anyone looking for an answer, this is a working example

```
Sub loadFile()

   Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
   Const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0

   Dim fs, f, ts, script

   Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set f = fs.GetFile("C:\test.js")
   Set ts = f.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading, TristateUseDefault)
   script = ts.ReadAll

   Debug.Print script
   ts.Close

End Sub
```