# How to utilize a JavaScript library (jsPDF)

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

Some Background:
I've been looking for a way to programmatically create a pdf from a collection of images.  It’s possible to do 90% of what I need through Word automation, but the problem is you can’t disable JPEG conversion when exporting to a PDF.  Originally, I had hoped there’d be a free command line utility out there, but that’s not the case.
The best thing I could find is the JavaScript library [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF).  I know almost nothing about Javascript, but library seems easy enough to use from the documentation.

[This page](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/snippets/scriptcontrol) has an extremely basic example of using JavaScript with VBA.  Sadly there’s very little information out there on doing this kind of thing.

The only relevant thing I could find on Stackoverflow is this [one unresolved post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376533/vba-for-excel-how-to-load-a-js-file-as-jscript-scriptcontrol-object?answertab=active#tab-top).  I attempted the same method here and not surprisingly, it didn’t work.  I get an error stating saying “syntax error” on the add code line.

```
Sub PDF1()
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim script As String
script = fso.OpenTextFile("***\jsPDF-master\src\jspdf.js", 1,   False).ReadAll

‘This requires a reference to Microsoft Script Control 1.0
Dim o As New ScriptControl
o.Language = "JScript"
With o

    .AddCode script

End With

End Sub
```

I really doubt this is the right approach. The entire library is probably 20k+ lines of code.  Is what I’m trying to do even possible?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Any other suggestions of alternate methods creating PDFs would also be helpful.

Comment: Apart from security concerns, ScriptControl is a 32bit only OCX and won't work on 64 bit office. Can't you use CDN? One way of using JS in VBA is through WebBrowser control. Look at this link, it uses HighCharts.js to create charts in VBA. http://ashuvba.blogspot.com/2015/01/java-script-chart-in-excel.html

Comment: Apparently it is possible to use ScriptControl on the 64 bit using [this work around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725882/getting-scriptcontrol-to-work-with-excel-2010-x64).  I'm also using the 32 bit version anyway. I will try out the method you linked to.