# Get "href=link" from html page and navigate to that link using vba

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am writing a code in Excel VBA to get `href` value of a class and navigate to that href link 
(i.e) here is the `href` value I want to get into my particular Excel sheet and I want to navigate to that link automatically through my VBA code.

```
<a href="/questions/51509457/how-to-make-the-word-invisible-when-its-checked-without-js" class="question-hyperlink">How to make the word invisible when it's checked without js</a>
```

The result I'm getting is that I'm able to get that containing tag's class value `How to make the word invisible when it's checked without js` <---- this is title is what I am getting in my sheet. What I want to get is this title's holding a `href` link `/questions/51509457/how-to-make-the-word-invisible-when-its-checked-without-js` this is what I want to get and navigate through my code.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance

Below are the entire coding:

```
Sub useClassnames()
    Dim element As IHTMLElement
    Dim elements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim html As HTMLDocument

    'open Internet Explorer in memory, and go to website
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "https://stackoverflow.com/questions"
    'Wait until IE has loaded the web page

    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set html = ie.document
    Set elements = html.getElementsByClassName("question-hyperlink")

    Dim count As Long
    Dim erow As Long
    count = 0

    For Each element In elements
        If element.className = "question-hyperlink" Then
            erow = Sheets("Exec").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
            Sheets("Exec").Cells(erow, 1) = html.getElementsByClassName("question-hyperlink")(count).innerText
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next element

    Range("H10").Select
End Sub
```

I cant find any answer in this website asked by anyone. Please don't suggest this question as duplicate.

```
<div class="row hoverSensitive">
        <div class="column summary-column summary-column-icon-compact  ">
                                <img src="images/app/run32.png" alt="" width="32" height="32">
                        </div>
        <div class="column summary-column  ">
            <div class="summary-title summary-title-compact text-ppp">
                                        <a href="**index.php?/runs/view/7552**">MMDA</a>

            </div>
            <div class="summary-description-compact text-secondary text-ppp">
                                                                            By on 7/9/2018                                                  </div>
        </div>      
        <div class="column summary-column summary-column-bar  ">
                            <div class="table">
<div class="column">
    <div class="chart-bar ">
                                                                                                                        <div class="chart-bar-custom link-tooltip" tooltip-position="left" style="background: #4dba0f; width: 125px" tooltip-text="100% Passed (11/11 tests)"></div>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            </div>
</div>
    <div class="column chart-bar-percent chart-bar-percent-compact">
    100%'
```

Comment: it looks like where you have innerText you need getAttribute("href")

Comment: am not getting blank cell if I did this

Comment: is there any other way?

Comment: @JeremyKahan is there any other way.

Comment: can anyone pls explain for this below code:

Comment: Was this answered?

Answer (score 1):

### Method ①

**Use XHR to make initial request using question homepage URL; apply CSS selector to retrieve links and then pass those links to IE to navigate to**

---

**CSS selectors to select elements:**

You want the `href` attribute of the element.You have been given an example already. You can use getAttribute, or, as pointed out by @Santosh, combine an `href` attribute CSS selector with other CSS selectors to target the elements.

CSS selector:

```
a.question-hyperlink[href]
```

Looks for elements with parent `a` tag having class of `question-hyperlink` and an `href` attribute.

You then apply the CSS selector combination with the `querySelectorAll` method of `document` to gather a nodeList of the links.

---

**XHR to get initial list of links:**

I would issue this first as an XHR, as much faster, and gather your links into a collection/nodeList you can later loop with your IE browser.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetLinks()
    Dim sResponse As String, HTML As New HTMLDocument, linkList As Object, i As Long
    Const BASE_URL As String = "https://stackoverflow.com"
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://stackoverflow.com/questions", False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))

    With HTML
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        Set linkList = .querySelectorAll("a.question-hyperlink[href]")
        For i = 0 To linkList.Length - 1
            Debug.Print Replace$(linkList.item(i), "about:", BASE_URL)
        Next i
    End With
    'Code using IE and linkList
End Sub
```

In the above `linkList` is a nodeList holding all the matched elements from the homepage i.e. all the `href`s on the question landing page. You can loop the `.Length` of the `nodeList` and index into it to retrieve a particular `href` e.g.  linkList.item(i). As the link returned is relative, you need to replace the relative `about:` part of the path with the protocol + domain i.e.  `"https://stackoverflow.com"`.

Now that you have quickly obtained that list, and can access items, you can pass any given updated `href` onto `IE.Navigate`.

---

**Navigating to questions using IE and nodeList**

```
For i = 0 To linkList.Length - 1
    IE.Navigate Replace$(linkList.item(i).getAttribute("href"), "about:", BASE_URL)
Next i
```

---

### Method ②

**Use XHR to make initial request using GET request and searched for question title; apply CSS selector to retrieve links and then pass those links to IE to navigate to.**

---

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetLinks()
    Dim sResponse As String, HTML As New HTMLDocument, linkList As Object, i As Long
    Const BASE_URL As String = "https://stackoverflow.com"
    Const TARGET_QUESTION As String = "How to make the word invisible when it's checked without js"
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=" & URLEncode(TARGET_QUESTION), False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))

    With HTML
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        Set linkList = .querySelectorAll("a.question-hyperlink[href]")
        For i = 0 To linkList.Length - 1
            Debug.Print Replace$(linkList.item(i).getAttribute("href"), "about:", BASE_URL)
        Next i
    End With
    If linkList Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    'Code using IE and linkList
End Sub

'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218181/how-can-i-url-encode-a-string-in-excel-vba   @Tomalak
Public Function URLEncode( _
   StringVal As String, _
   Optional SpaceAsPlus As Boolean = False _
) As String

  Dim StringLen As Long: StringLen = Len(StringVal)

  If StringLen > 0 Then
    ReDim result(StringLen) As String
    Dim i As Long, CharCode As Integer
    Dim Char As String, Space As String

    If SpaceAsPlus Then Space = "+" Else Space = "%20"

    For i = 1 To StringLen
      Char = Mid$(StringVal, i, 1)
      CharCode = Asc(Char)
      Select Case CharCode
        Case 97 To 122, 65 To 90, 48 To 57, 45, 46, 95, 126
          result(i) = Char
        Case 32
          result(i) = Space
        Case 0 To 15
          result(i) = "%0" & Hex(CharCode)
        Case Else
          result(i) = "%" & Hex(CharCode)
      End Select
    Next i
    URLEncode = Join(result, "")
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: To avoid `.getAttribute("href")` in for loop  use `.querySelectorAll("a.question-hyperlink[href]")`

Comment: Not really once you change, the value can be accessed using `Debug.Print linkList(i)`

Comment: Did this answer your question @MDI ?

Answer (score 0):

1. This `If element.className = "question-hyperlink" Then` is useless because it is always true because you `getElementsByClassName("question-hyperlink")` so all elements are definitely of class `question-hyperlink`. The `If` statement can be removed.
2. You have each link in the variable `element` so you don't need the `count`. Instead of `html.getElementsByClassName("question-hyperlink")(count).innerText` use `element.innerText`.

So it should look like this:

```
Set elements = html.getElementsByClassName("question-hyperlink")
Dim erow As Long

For Each element In elements
    erow = Worksheets("Exec").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Worksheets("Exec").Cells(erow, 1) = element.innerText
    Worksheets("Exec").Cells(erow, 2) = element.GetAttribute("href") 'this should give you the URL
Next element
```