# VBA access DB posting XML to php server changes &amp; to ["amp_

Tags: php, xml, ms-access, vba, ampersand

I am having an issue reading XML in php sent from an access database when the body contains &. When when I receive content that contains & in the body  it seems that the & is converted to ["amp; somewhere in the process and the whole xml is malformed as a result. This is an example of what I am sending and receiving:

```
xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><query><author>John Steinbeck</author></query>"

Dim objHTTP As New ServerXMLHTTP60
objHTTP.Open "POST", "http://localhost/sandpit/testxml.php", False      
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"      
objHTTP.send "request=" & xml
```

The php file is just a simple echo request for testing:

```
<?php echo "<xmp>posted: ";var_dump($_REQUEST);echo "</xmp>"; ?>
```

When the author body does not contain an ampersand the result in PHP is:

```
["request"]=>
    string(84) "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><query><author>John 
    Steinbeck</author></query>"
    }
```

However, if I change the xml string to:

```
xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><query><author>John &amp; Steinbeck</author></query>"
```

the result I get is:

```
posted: array(2) {
    ["request"]=>
    string(41) "<?xml version='1.0'?><query><author>John "
    ["amp;_Steinbeck</author></query>"]=>
    string(0) ""
}
```

You can see above that & is converted to ['amp....

Also tried using CDATA with the following result:

```
posted: array(2) {
    ["request"]=>
    string(68) "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><query><author><! 
    [CDATA[ John "
    ["Steinbeck]]></author></query>"]=>
    string(0) ""
```

}

Seems everything after the ampersand to the end of the xml string is enclosed in ["..."] which messes up the xml.

Also tried changing the content type to text/xml and application/xml in which case I get an empty string.

I have tested sending the same xml with CURL in php and works fine using content type text/xml and even text/html.

Anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: CDATA, didn't work?  That seems strange.  What are you parsing the XML with?  I've used [XMLReader](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) with great success in the past.  I never had much luck with things like DOM or SimpleXml.  The only time I had real problems with the & was when the XML was consumed by Quickbooks, but that was ages ago, maybe 8 years ago.  I'd hope they sorted that out by now.

Comment: @Nick Yeah I saw that article and tried that but anything with an ampersand is affected

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I am using simplexml but the problem is the XML is malformed on arrival so simplexml just throws it out as invalid.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I've retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 1):

You're submitting your data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` without url encoding your content.

In url encoded data, the `&` separates two arguments, so PHP is correctly interpreting your data with the specified encoding, you're just encoding it wrong. This is not an XML problem, it's an URL encoding problem.

In url encoding, the ampersand can be escaped by using `%26` instead of an ampersand.

VBA doesn't come with an URL encoder. Either use a different encoding scheme, write your own, or use one provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218181/7296893)

Comment: Thanks Erik, I realise it wasn't an issue with XML but rather the headers and I didn't want to encode the xml so I implemented the workaround of using php://input instead. But yes, encoding with %26 would probably have worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround and reasonable explanation in this article:

[PHP "php://input" vs $_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post)

I suspected the content type in the headers may be the issue which led to this article so rather than using $_POST or $_REQUEST to get the input, you need to get the raw input, eg  $xml = file_get_contents('php://input');

I am using Symfony request so the raw content can be fetched with $request->getContent().

When you use the content type of text/xml, it should work as it does in php but seems that PHP superglobals filters that out which is why I got an empty string, but the raw input can still be read using php://input.