# I want to insert API Key in the Geocoding macro

Tags: excel, vba, google-geocoding-api

This is the code that already exists. Now i need to insert API Key in the program and make it work. Where and how should I insert API key ?

```
Sub Geocode()
'
Dim counter1 As Long
Dim Address As String
Dim Longitude As Double
Dim Latitude As Double
Dim Success As Boolean
Dim Status As String
counter1 = 2
Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(counter1, 1))
    Cells(counter1, 5) = Cells(counter1, 1) & ", " & Cells(counter1, 2) & ", " & Cells(counter1, 3) & ", " & Cells(counter1, 4)
    Address = Cells(counter1, 5)
    Success = GetLongitudeAndLatitude(Address, Longitude, Latitude, Status)
            If Success = True Then
                Cells(counter1, 7) = Longitude
                Cells(counter1, 6) = Latitude
            Else
                Cells(counter1, 6) = Status
                Cells(counter1, 7) = Status
            End If
    counter1 = counter1 + 1
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
Loop

Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.ClearContents

End Sub





Private Function GetLongitudeAndLatitude(Address As String, Longitude As Double, Latitude As Double, Status As String) As Boolean

    ' Declare variables and set return value to false by default
    GetLongitudeAndLatitude = False
    Dim response As DOMDocument60
    Dim http As XMLHTTP60
    Dim node As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim nodes As IXMLDOMNodeList
    Set http = New XMLHTTP60

    ' Read the data from the website
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Open an XML request from Google using their GeoCode API
    http.Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" & URLEncode(Address), False
    http.send
    Set response = http.responseXML

    ' get the status node.  This node tells you whether your search succeeded - OK means success.  Any other status means some kind of error or address not found.
    Set node = response.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/status")
    If node.nodeTypedValue <> "OK" Then
        Status = node.nodeTypeString
    Else
        Set nodes = response.SelectNodes("/GeocodeResponse/result")
        ' check for multiple addresses if we found more than 1 result then error out.
        If nodes.Length > 1 Then
            MsgBox ("Found Multiple Matches for Address: " & Address)
        Else
            ' grab the latitude and longitude from the XML response
            Set node = response.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat")
            Latitude = node.nodeTypedValue
            Set node = response.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng")
            Longitude = node.nodeTypedValue
            GetLongitudeAndLatitude = True
        End If

    End If

    Set http = Nothing
    Set response = Nothing

End Function

' URL Encoding function courtesy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218181/how-can-i-url-encode-a-string-in-excel-vba
Private Function URLEncode( _
   StringVal As String, _
   Optional SpaceAsPlus As Boolean = False _
) As String

  Dim StringLen As Long: StringLen = Len(StringVal)

  If StringLen > 0 Then
    ReDim result(StringLen) As String
    Dim i As Long, CharCode As Integer
    Dim Char As String, Space As String

    If SpaceAsPlus Then Space = "+" Else Space = "%20"

    For i = 1 To StringLen
      Char = Mid$(StringVal, i, 1)
      CharCode = Asc(Char)
      Select Case CharCode
        Case 97 To 122, 65 To 90, 48 To 57, 45, 46, 95, 126
          result(i) = Char
        Case 32
          result(i) = Space
        Case 0 To 15
          result(i) = "%0" & Hex(CharCode)
        Case Else
          result(i) = "%" & Hex(CharCode)
      End Select
    Next i
    URLEncode = Join(result, "")
  End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key) actually helps here:

> [image]

So you need to add your key here

```
Const API_KEY As String = "your key here"
http.Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" & URLEncode(Address) & "&key=" & API_KEY, False
```

Comment: It is returning 'element' which is the default value of the data type 'String'

Comment: a) I don't understand what you want to tell me because that is even not a question. b) Note that we cannot answer follow-up questions in comments (this site is question/answer based not a forum). You asked where to put the key, so I can only give the answer to that. If you have a completely new issue now (which it is, if it is not directly related to where to put the API-KEY) you should mark this one as solved and ask a new question and describe well what your new issue is (including which error you get exactly and where in your code).

Comment: And remove `On Error Resume Next`. This line just hides all error messages but the errors don't disappear, you just cannot see them. If you don't see them you cannot fix them. If you don't fix them it will not work.