# "Signature not valid" when getting API data (VBA-Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, api, sha256, sha

I have an issue when I try to retrieve some data in excel through VBA code.
I used the following as basis: https://github.com/BitMEX/api-connectors/tree/master/official-http/vba
and it works, I was able to update it according to my need and place an order (testnet)

I now try to retrieve the book but I always get "Signature not valid" as response.
Can you please help understand what's I am doing wrong?

The data I want to receive is the following:
https://testnet.bitmex.com/api/explorer/#!/OrderBook/OrderBook_getL2

As Hash function, I use the HexHash function available in the link provided above (and it works for the 'Post' instruction but can't make it works for the "GET" instruction.

Thanks in advance

Bellow a working code (POST function):

```
Sub placeorder()
Dim Json, httpObject As Object
Dim nonce As Double
Dim verb, apiKey, apiSecret, signature, symbol, price, qty, url, postdata, replytext, nonceStr As String

' Set monotonically (w time) increasing nonce
nonce = DateDiff("s", "1/1/1970", Now)

' Set api key and secret
apiKey = "aaa"
apiSecret = "bbb"

' Build query
symbol = "XBTUSD"
price = 8000
qty = 1

verb = "POST"
url = "/api/v1/order"
postdata = "symbol=" & symbol & "&price=" & price & "&quantity=" & qty

' Stringize nonce
nonceStr = nonce

' Compute signature using hexhash script
signature = HexHash.HexHash(verb + url + nonceStr + postdata, apiSecret, "SHA256")

' Set up HTTP req with headers
Set httpObject = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
httpObject.Open "POST", "https://testnet.bitmex.com" & url, False
httpObject.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
httpObject.setRequestHeader "api-nonce", nonceStr
httpObject.setRequestHeader "api-key", apiKey
httpObject.setRequestHeader "api-signature", signature
httpObject.Send (postdata)

' Catch response
replytext = httpObject.ResponseText

end sub()
```

Bellow a NON-working code (GET function):

```
Sub getorderbook2()
Dim Json, httpObject As Object
Dim nonce As Double
Dim verb, apiKey, apiSecret, signature, symbol, url, getdata, replytext, 
depth As String
Dim nonceStr As String

' Set monotonically (w time) increasing nonce
nonce = DateDiff("s", "1/1/1970", Now)

' Set api key and secret
apiKey = "aaa"
apiSecret = "bbb"

' Build query
symbol = "XBTUSD"
depth = 3

verb = "GET"
url = "/api/v1/orderBook/L2"
getdata = "symbol=" & symbol & "&depth=" & depth

' Stringize nonce
nonceStr = nonce

' Compute signature using hexhash script
signature = HexHash.HexHash(verb + url + nonceStr + getdata, apiSecret, "SHA256")

' Set up HTTP req with headers
Set httpObject = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
httpObject.Open "GET", "https://testnet.bitmex.com" & url, False
httpObject.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
httpObject.setRequestHeader "api-nonce", nonceStr
httpObject.setRequestHeader "api-key", apiKey
httpObject.setRequestHeader "api-signature", signature
httpObject.Send (getdata)

' Catch response
replytext = httpObject.ResponseText
end sub ()
```

In the second section, I always get an error message in return "Signature not valid"

Comment: I'm not quite sure about the code to be honest... is difficult to test without having all the facts. However, putting this codes side by side, `"application/application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` doesn't seem right in the second one... should have been `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` ?

Comment: Thanks, it is a copy past isssue when creating the message on my side. The original code was correct: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and it still have the "Signature no valid" with this. When you say "without having all the facts"', can you let me know what additional information you need? I can load the excel file directly if necessary :)

Comment: By all facts I mean all the other details you can't post for security reasons, i.e.: key, secret, etc. I didn't mean you haven't added as much as possible already. Plus, debugging API is not exactly my strong suit, just thought to comment on the bit I was able to test easily.

Comment: @Bounty25 So if I understand correctly there's no problem with the code itself. It runs just fine but if you print `replytext` you get "Signature not valid" instead of an HTML response you would normally expect to get? If that's the case, maybe there's a problem in the way/logic with which you compute the `signature`.

Comment: Yes you’re right, I get « Signature not valid ». And it makes me crazy as I use the same method to comput the signature in the first code and it works so I don’t understand what I am doing wrong in the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching between GET and POST requires more than just changing the verb in the request. A GET request needs to have the data as part of the URL string so try:

```
url = url & "?" & getdata
getdata = ""
httpObject.Open "GET", "https://testnet.bitmex.com" & url, False
```

You also need to change this line from:

```
httpObject.Send (getdata)
```

to:

```
httpObject.Send
```

The way in which you construct the `api-signature` value is also different for GET requests to this API - see [here](https://www.bitmex.com/app/apiKeysUsage#full-sample-calculation) for details. The changes I have suggested should lead to the correct signature being generated. If you need to URL encode data in VBA then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24301379/2127508) might help.

Other issues:

- `Dim a, b As String` is equivalent to `Dim a As Variant, b As String`. To declare multiple String variables you need to write `Dim a As String, b As String`
- `CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")` accesses the older version 3.0 of MSXML2. To access the most recent version 6.0, you need `CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")`

Comment: Many thanks for this answer. I’m not able to implement it today but will try tomorrow and let you know.