# How do I send an Arabic sms via API from access form vba

Tags: vba, api, ms-access, sms

I have access to a database with a phone number, 
I want to send an Arabic sms to the phone number,
I use this code to send:

```
Dim result As String
Dim myUrl As String

Dim winHttpReq As Object
Set winHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
myUrl = "http://www.nsms.ps/api.php?comm=sendsms&user=user&pass=pass&to=number&message=مرحبا&sender=TrueMark"
    winHttpReq.Open "GET", myUrl, False
    winHttpReq.Send

    result = winHttpReq.responseText
```

My code is working and I receive an sms to my phone, but I did not receive it in Arabic word order.
I receive it like this: `ط§ظ„ط³ظ„ط§ظ… ط¹ظ„ظٹظƒظ…`

Answer (score 0):

URLs generally need to be UTF-8 encoded or percent-encoded.

These are pretty broad subjects, but luckily, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3812363/7296893) contains a percent-encoder that supports unicode. Use it to percent-encode the Arabic characters in your URL. It just needs to be adjusted for 64-bit operations if you want to use it on 64-bit Access.

If you want to go the UTF-8 way, you'll need to replace the COM WinHTTPRequest object with [WinHTTP Flat API calls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttp-functions), and call `WideCharToMultiByte` to convert the string from UTF-16 to UTF-8. That's not a trivial task, unfortunately.

Comment: thanks , but how can i use WideCharToMultiByte  in my code ?

Comment: As said, not a trivial task. If you can't figure that out yourself, go for the first solution.

Comment: can you explain more ?

Comment: Eh... Not really unless I know what you want explained. If you just copy-paste the first solution and run that over the Arabic text before putting it in the URL, it should just work.