# Excel QR Generation Issues - & +

Tags: excel, vba, qr-code

So I have been using the following VBA Module code to generate QR codes in a desired cell. The code works as expected for all desired ASCII values expect '&' and '+'. If any of these characters is mid string example - Jack & Jill - only 'Jack' would be displayed, ie anything after, and including, the '&' would be cut off. Similar story with the '+'.

Thanks in advance

```
  Function Insert_QR(codetext As String)
    Dim URL As String, MyCell As Range​
​
    Set MyCell = Application.Caller​
    URL = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=125x125&cht=qr&chl=" & codetext​
    On Error Resume Next​
      ActiveSheet.Pictures("My_QR_" & MyCell.Address(False, False)).Delete 'delete if there is prevoius one​
    On Error GoTo 0​
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(URL).Select​
    With Selection.ShapeRange(1)​
     .PictureFormat.CropLeft = 10​
     .PictureFormat.CropRight = 10​
     .PictureFormat.CropTop = 10​
     .PictureFormat.CropBottom = 10​
     .Name = "My_QR_" & MyCell.Address(False, False)​
     .Left = MyCell.Left + 25​
     .Top = MyCell.Top + 5​
    End With​
    Insert_QR = "" ' or some text to be displayed behind code​
End Function​
```

Comment: This is an issue with `https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?` which is deprecated.

Comment: @chrisneilsen thanks for the reply, do you know of a similar URL which i copuld just switch out for

Comment: I don't know one specifically , but I'd follow the links Google provide

Answer (score 0):

First thing first Google Image Charts is deprecated and can be shutdown anytime soon. There are alternatives like [Image-Charts](https://www.image-charts.com).

Regarding your issue `codetext` needs to be URLEncoded. If you are using Excel 2013+ you can use

```vb
URL = "https://image-charts.com/chart?chs=125x125&cht=qr&chl=" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeUrl(codetext)
```

Otherwise you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/218199/745121) that provide an `URLEncode` function that will also encode query params in order to generate the static QR code image.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lay within the fact that the QR codes were being generated by URL. the above characters are what are known as URL restricted characters therefore cannot be repreneted in URL. therefore to represent '&' in URL == '%26'