# I forgot an Excel formula that changes text to URL format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

There is a formula in Excel that changes normal text to how it would look in a URL. For example, from `sci-fi movies @netflix` to `sci-fi+movies+%40netflix`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I URL encode a string in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218181/how-can-i-url-encode-a-string-in-excel-vba)

Comment: that one? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/encodeurl-function-07c7fb90-7c60-4bff-8687-fac50fe33d0e ... if so, google is your friend

Comment: @Argee thanks... its ENCODEURL... tysm

Comment: @Argee add this answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for [this one from support.microsoft.com](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/encodeurl-function-07c7fb90-7c60-4bff-8687-fac50fe33d0e)...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any formula that converts a normal text to URL format.
but if you know what is the criteria for converting text to URL you can create a custom function

Comment: but if you need google search URL (no specific website) then 1 possible solution is to create a macro that searches the text in google and copy the searched result URL in excel sheet

Comment: its 'ENCODEURL'... thanks to @Argee for commenting answer