# Ignoring wildcard function of FollowHyperlink within a text string in VBA

Tags: vba, string, ms-access, wildcard

I am trying to open a file path in Explorer using the `.FollowHyperlink` method and get errors on the strings with the "#" character. How do I format the string to make `.FollowHyperlink` ignore the wildcard functionality? For instance how would I format the following file path:

`G:\Building\#500 Main St.\Loans\`

Comment: What are you trying to open? It helps to explain what you are doing because there is no such thing as a wildcard to a string.

Comment: Hi @hackslash,   
I've copied the file path of a folder in a variable passed to the  .followhyperlink() method in order to open the target folder in windows explorer.

This works for 95% of the folder paths. The remaining 5% failures are all folder paths with the "#" character somewhere in the string.  Removing the # removes the error. As # is a wildcard in excel, I assumed that I just need to "exit" that functionality as you can tell from my initial post.

I know I can rename the folder names to remove the "#" but would like to understand how vba is handling #s in my string.

Comment: If you are opening a folder in explorer then the answer from @Tim Williams below is correct.

Comment: @hackslash, I agree the shell function solution below does work. However, I think is a little less desirable as the .followhyperlink() method will reuse explorer windows and doesn't result in several windows and dupe windows. I've fixed my problem (just removed the # from all folders) in this specific case, I'm am now hoping someone can help me understand why the .followhyperlink() method errors out with "#" in the text string. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can tell by looking at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Access.Application.FollowHyperlink) that the first argument is expected to be an `Address` which must follow the rules of a valid URI as defined in the [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt).

The hash `#` is a reserved symbol in the URI RFC.

You would have to URL Encode any string you pass in to it to avoid reserved symbols. There is no built-in method to URL encode strings in Access, but there is in Excel.

You can see a full discussion of URL Encode in VBA here:
[How can I URL encode a string in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218181/how-can-i-url-encode-a-string-in-excel-vba/24301379#24301379)

Here is an example of your URL encoded local path:

```
FollowHyperlink("G%3A%5CBuilding%5C%23500%20Main%20St.%5CLoans%5C")
```

Comment: my newb programming brain is going to have to study this for quite a while, but what a great answer! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Shell for this:

```
Shell "C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe ""G:\Building\#500 Main St.\Loans\""", vbNormalFocus
```