# VBA Google Translate Macro Omits Special Characters

Tags: excel, vba

I'm learning Excel VBA, and want to write a macro function to translate values in the excel cells using google translate. So far I've:

```
Function GTranslate(strInput As String, strFromLang As String, strToLang As String) As String
    Dim strURL As String, objHTTP As Object, objHTML As Object, objDivs As Object, objDiv As Variant
    
    strInput = WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(strInput)
    strURL = "https://translate.google.com/m?hl=" & strFromLang & _
        "&sl=" & strFromLang & _
        "&tl=" & strToLang & _
        "&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q=" & strInput
        
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    objHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 10.0)"
    objHTTP.Send ""
    
    Set objHTML = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    With objHTML
        .Open
        .Write objHTTP.responseText
        .Close
    End With
    
    Set objDivs = objHTML.getElementsByTagName("div")
    For Each objDiv In objDivs
        If objDiv.className = "result-container" Then
            GTranslate = objDiv.innerText: Exit For
        End If
    Next objDiv
    
    Set objHTML = Nothing: Set objHTTP = Nothing
End Function
```

The thing with this code is that if the Input String contains special character (like double quote ""), the Function will just ignore them and omit them in the result string. Is there any workaround? Thanks in advance.

I suppose this has something to do with encoding, but I can't figure out what to change.

Comment: maybe try with WorksheetFunction.EncodeUrl(strInput) (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218181/how-can-i-url-encode-a-string-in-excel-vba/24301379#24301379)

Comment: If I translate the word "hombre" manually then this gives "man". Why is this not correct?

Comment: @user10186832, If the input string is "mujer «hombre»", then I get female Male"